# Replace single quotes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replace, error-handling

I have this function in SQL Server to replace single quotes.

But when I insert a single quote it throws an error on `Replace(@strip,''',''))`:

```
Create Function [dbo].[fn_stripsingleQuote]
    (@strStrip varchar(Max))
    returns varchar
as
begin
    declare @CleanString varchar(Max)
    SET @var=(Replace(@strip,'',''))

    return @var
end
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You need to double up your single quotes as follows:

```
REPLACE(@strip, '''', '')
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem but using your technique i get  **`syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`**

Comment: REPLACE(@WAREHOUSE, '''', '''''')

Answer (score 31):

Try `REPLACE(@strip,'''','')`

`SQL` uses two quotes to represent one in a string.

Answer (score 27):

If you really must completely strip out the single quotes you can do this:

```
Replace(@strip, '''', '')
```

However, ordinarily you'd replace ' with '' and this will make SQL Server happy when querying the database. The trick with any of the built-in SQL functions (like replace) is that they too require you to double up your single quotes.

So to replace ' with '' in code you'd do this:

```
Replace(@strip, '''', '''''')
```

Of course... in some situations you can avoid having to do this entirely if you use parameters when querying the database. Say you're querying the database from a .NET application, then you'd use the [SqlParameter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(VS.71).aspx) to feed the SqlCommand parameters for the query and all of this single quote business will be taken care of automatically. This is usually the preferred method as SQL parameters will also help prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, was looking for how to replace ' with '' :)

Answer (score 10):

You could use char(39)

```
insert into my_table values('hi, my name'+char(39)+'s tim.')
```

Or in this case:

```
Replace(@strip,char(39),'')
```

Comment: The beauty of this solution is that it's easier to read in certain circumstances. Thank you.

Comment: This is always my preferred way of doing it. Double and quadruple quotes looks messy and is harder to maintain. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're trying to duplicate the [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) functionality. This built-in function can be used to add delimiters and properly escape delimiters inside strings and recognizes both single `'` and double `"` quotes as delimiters, as well as brackets `[` and `]`.

Comment: QUOTENAME is for T-SQL identifiers. Unfortunately not appropriate for data.

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the single quote with a single quote:

```
Replace(@strip, '''', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

We have to double the number of quotes.

**To replace single quote :**

```
REPLACE(@strip, '''', '')
```

**To replace double quotes :**

```
REPLACE(@strip, '''''', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If escaping your single quote with another single quote isn't working for you (like it didn't for one of my recent REPLACE() queries), you can use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF before your query, then SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON after.

For example

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

UPDATE TABLE SET NAME = REPLACE(NAME, "'S", "S");

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
```

Comment: It seems like the OP is not understanding why putting a single quote inside single quotes does not work. Changing the way identifiers are quoted is unlikely to fix that. Also, this question is 3 years old...

Comment: The OP said his function's purpose was to replace a single quote. My solution is indeed a valid approach to that function. Also, If other users find that the answers to this question don't help with REPLACE(), as in my case, this solution may indeed be helpful. In short, my answer may be helpful to others, if not necessarily the OP. And what difference does the age of a question make if it's helpful to the community?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a strange anomaly that would apply here.  Using Google API and getting the reply in XML format, it was failing to convert to XML data type because of single quotes.

Replace(@Strip ,'''','')

was not working because the single quote was ascii character 146 instead of 39.
So I used:

Replace(@Strip, char(146), '')

which also works for regular single quotes char(39) and any other special character.

Comment: There is no ASCII character 146. Extended ASCII defines other characters, like some international characters, graphics, and symbols. `char(146)` corresponds to a Latin Æ in that character set. If that expression works, it doesn't correspond to anything that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select replace (colname, char(39)+char(39), '') AS colname FROM .[dbo].[Db Name];
```

I have achieved the desired result.
Example : Input value -->  *Like '%Pat') '' OR*

```
      Want Output -->  *Like '%Pat') OR*
```

using above query achieved the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The striping/replacement/scaping of single quotes from user input ([input sanitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Preventing_SQL_injection)), has to be done *before* the SQL statement reaches the database.

Comment: It can be done on the inserts aswell, so the admin is not only on the dba

Comment: this implies sprocs open to sql injection are ok. i do not agree with this implication.

Comment: What if the coder interacting with the server instance is trying to deliberately create an SQL injection attack? There should be some validation/sanitation done on the T-SQL/database end as well, especially for stored procs as implied by @JohnDhom

Answer (score 0):

Besides needing to escape the quote (by using double quotes), you've also confused the names of variables: You're using @var and @strip, instead of @CleanString and @strStrip...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the shortest SQL statement for that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_stripsingleQuote] (@strStrip varchar(Max))
    RETURNS varchar(Max)
AS
BEGIN    
    RETURN (Replace(@strStrip ,'''',''))
END
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

select  replace ( colname, '''', '') AS  colname FROM .[dbo].[Db Name]