# How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, delimiter, single-quotes

I am trying to `insert` some text data into a table in SQL Server 9.

The text includes a single quote `'`.

How do I escape that?

I tried using two single quotes, but it threw me some errors.

eg. `insert into my_table values('hi, my name''s tim.');`

Comment: "it threw me some errors" -- What were these errors?

Comment: Yes because the right way to insert single quotes in MSSQL is to double them. The example you show us should be working. How to you make this SQL query, with which language ? Or is it in SQL Server Management Studio ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Replace single quotes in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440733/replace-single-quotes-in-sql-server)*.

Answer (score 1950, accepted):

**Single quotes are escaped by doubling them up**, just as you've shown us in your example. The following SQL illustrates this functionality. I tested it on SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @my_table TABLE (
    [value] VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO @my_table VALUES ('hi, my name''s tim.')

SELECT * FROM @my_table
```

#### Results

```
value
==================
hi, my name's tim.
```

Comment: i was looking at the wrong place to fix my problem. it was not a character escape issue after all. my issue was that the data length was over the limit. thanks for reassuring me that using the single quote twice is the right way of escaping the character.

Comment: So, if I have a text containing 10k words it'll be necessary I replace all my text?

Comment: @ViniciusLima: The short answer is yes. That would change of course depending on the technology you're going to use to store the data. If you're using an ORM it will do it for you. If you're building your SQL commands manually you'll want to use the language's "prepared statements" functionality. If you're doing it in Management Studio then you'll have to do the replace.

Comment: i.e. two single quotes for one. [''] => [']

Answer (score 92):

If escaping your single quote with another single quote isn't working for you (like it didn't for one of my recent `REPLACE()` queries), you can use `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` before your query, then `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` after your query.

For example

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

UPDATE TABLE SET NAME = REPLACE(NAME, "'S", "S");

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
-- set OFF then ON again
```

Comment: Normally I use the doubled up approach, but where I was generating dynamic SQL which was then ran across multiple servers and databases, this solution worked for me whereas the doubling didn't in one specific case. Thanks for this!

Comment: Be careful when referencing views and indexes on computed columns or you may get an error.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235527/incorrect-set-options-error-when-building-database-project

Comment: @RichardMoss, +1. same scenario with you. doubled up approach is the initial solution. For complex queries like dynamic SQL across multiple servers, this will work, doubled up approach may not

Comment: It's worth noting for the uninitiated that `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` alters the behavior of the double-quote and not the behavior of the apostrophe.  In particular, setting its value to `OFF` means that a double quote can be used for delimiting strings.  With it turned `ON` (the default) it is used for delimiting identifiers, like column names, so that they can contain spaces or SQL keywords.

Answer (score 74):

How about:

```
insert into my_table values('hi, my name' + char(39) + 's tim.')
```

Answer (score 73):

Many of us know that the Popular Method of Escaping Single Quotes is by **Doubling them up** easily like below.

```
PRINT 'It''s me, Arul.';
```

[image: Doubling the Single Quotes Method]

we are going to look on some ***other alternate ways of escaping the single quotes***.

**1. UNICODE Characters**

39 is the UNICODE character of Single Quote. So we can use it like below.

```
PRINT 'Hi,it'+CHAR(39)+'s Arul.';
PRINT 'Helo,it'+NCHAR(39)+'s Arul.';
```

[image: UNICODE Characters]

**2. QUOTED_IDENTIFIER**

Another simple and best alternate solution is to use QUOTED_IDENTIFIER.
When QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is set to OFF, the strings can be enclosed in double quotes.
In this scenario, we don’t need to escape single quotes.
So,this way would be very helpful while using lot of string values with single quotes.
It will be very much helpful while using so many lines of INSERT/UPDATE scripts where column values having single quotes.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
PRINT "It's Arul."
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

[image: QUOTE_IDENTIFIER]

CONCLUSION

The above mentioned methods are applicable to both AZURE and On Premises .

Answer (score 25):

**2 ways to work around this:**

---

for `'` you can simply double it in the string, e.g. 
`select 'I''m happpy'` -- will get: `I'm happy`

---

For any charactor you are not sure of: in sql server you can get any char's unicode by `select unicode(':')` (you keep the number)

So this case you can also `select 'I'+nchar(39)+'m happpy'`

Answer (score 19):

The doubling up of the quote should have worked, so it's peculiar that it didn't work for you; however, an alternative is using double quote characters, instead of single ones, around the string.  I.e.,

`insert into my_table values("hi, my name's tim."`);

Comment: What if the text contains both single and double quotes? Also, aren't double quotes reserved for field names only?

Answer (score 6):

Also another thing to be careful of is whether or not it is really stored as a classic ASCII ' (ASCII 27) or Unicode 2019 (which looks similar, but not the same). 
This isn't a big deal on inserts, but it can mean the world on selects and updates. 
 If it's the unicode value then escaping the ' in a WHERE clause (e.g where blah = 'Workers''s Comp') will return like the value you are searching for isn't there if the ' in "Worker's Comp" is actually the unicode value.
If your client application supports free-key, as well as copy and paste based input, it could be Unicode in some rows, and ASCII in others!
A simple way to confirm this is by doing some kind of open ended query that will bring back the value you are searching for, and then copy and paste that into notepad++ or some other unicode supporting editor.
 The differing appearance between the ascii value and the unicode one should be obvious to the eyes, but if you lean towards the anal, it will show up as 27 (ascii) or 92 (unicode) in a hex editor.

Comment: Note that single quote is `char(39)`, not `char(27)`. 27 is the hex code for single quote. 39 is the decimal code for it.

Answer (score 5):

The following syntax will escape you ONLY ONE quotation mark:

```
SELECT ''''
```

The result will be  a single quote. Might be very helpful for creating dynamic SQL :).
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Double quotes option helped me

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
insert into my_table values("hi, my name's tim.");
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just insert a ' before anything to be inserted. It will be like an escape character in SQL Server

Example:

When you have a field as, **I'm fine**.

you can do:

```
UPDATE my_table SET row ='I''m fine.';
```

Comment: Isn’t that exactly what the OP did, and the same as the top-voted answer already says? Presumably there must have been some other source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
DECLARE @singleQuote CHAR 
SET @singleQuote =  CHAR(39)

insert into my_table values('hi, my name'+ @singleQuote +'s tim.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but mine was not based of static data in the SQL code itself, but from values in the data.

This code lists all the columns names and data types in my database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

But some column names actually have a single-quote embedded in the name of the column!, such as ...

```
[MyTable].[LEOS'DATACOLUMN]
```

To process these, I had to use the REPLACE function along with the suggested  QUOTED_IDENTIFIER setting. Otherwise it would be a syntax error, when the column is used in a dynamic SQL.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
    SET @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT ''' + @TableName + ''',''' + REPLACE(@ColumnName,"'","''") + ...etc
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Add N before value**

```
insert into my_table values(N'hi, my name's tim.');
```

Answer (score -3):

The [STRING_ESCAPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) funtion can be used on newer versions of SQL Server

Comment: According to the documentation: "Currently STRING_ESCAPE can only escape JSON special characters"

Comment: And it cannot be used for escape the ``'``

Answer (score -4):

This should work: use a back slash and put a double quote

```
"UPDATE my_table SET row =\"hi, my name's tim.\";
```

Comment: What do you mean? You are saying that `PRINT \"hi, my name's tim.\";` is going to work in SSMS?  It doesn't work at all and nobody has ever told that it works.