# Alertview in iphone application development

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to iphone application.In my current app.,I have uibutton(changepassword).my requirement is,when i click on the button,it will shows alertview which contains three textfileds(current password,newpassword,retype password) and two uibuttons(submitbutton,cancel button). can anyone send me the required code with explanation?

Comment: please format your post properly. unable to read it

Comment: This is the fifth question you've asked, and each one seems to simply be asking people to send you code for the next part of the application you're working on. Why not read a tutorial about writing iPhone apps and actually try and learn something rather than just copying and pasting code from the internet?

Comment: If you don't have time or care to even format your code, peoples won't bother to answer you question. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in sqlserver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 3):

```
// Create a new alert object and set initial values.
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                message:@"Message"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
// Display the alert to the user
[alert show];
// Release the alert
[alert release];
```

Examples and explanations here: http://iloveco.de/uikit-alert-types/

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: Your first link seems to be dead.