# can we escape single quote in sql server query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a  problem with the following query in SQL SERVER

```
select ecode,ename
  from VW_EFORMS_BillingAdjustmentCodes
 where ename='Ravi's friend';
```

In the Above Query "Ravi's Friend" is a string from DB. can i escape the single quote 
please help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in sqlserver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 6):

You can use two quotes:

```
'Ravi''s friend'
```

Or use a parameterized query and supply the string as a parameter:

```
SELECT ecode, ename
FROM VW_EFORMS_BillingAdjustmentCodes
WHERE ename = ?
```

Answer (score 3):

A single quote in a string is escaped by two single quotes in a row (`''`).

```
where ename='Ravi''s friend'
                 ^^ two ''
```