# 'Incorrect SET Options' Error When Building Database Project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-project

We are using Visual Studio and a database project to generate our database.

I just made a number of database changes (including adding a new table named `Correspondence`) imported those changes into the database project, and attempted to deploy (rebuild) the database.

When I do, I get the following error:

> Creating [dbo].[Correspondence]...
>   Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Server (Server Name), Line 1
>   CREATE TABLE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings
>   : 'ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use 
>   with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes
>   and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index
>   operations.

Can anyone explain this error to me, and help me resolve it? Here's the script the database project uses to create this table.

```
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[Correspondence]...';
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Correspondence] (
    [Id]                INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [WorkbookId]        INT              NOT NULL,
    [ProviderId]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [MessageThreadId]   INT              NOT NULL,
    [MessageThreadType] AS               ((1)) PERSISTED NOT NULL
);
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO

PRINT N'Creating PK_Correspondence...';
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Correspondence]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Correspondence] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF);
GO
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

According to [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175088.aspx):

> Indexed views and indexes on computed columns store results in the
>   database for later reference. The stored results are valid only if all
>   connections referring to the indexed view or indexed computed column
>   can generate the same result set as the connection that created the
>   index.

In order to create a table with a persisted, computed column, the following connection settings must be enabled:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

These values are set on the database level and can be viewed using:

```
SELECT 
    is_ansi_nulls_on,
    is_ansi_padding_on,
    is_ansi_warnings_on,
    is_arithabort_on,
    is_concat_null_yields_null_on,
    is_numeric_roundabort_on,
    is_quoted_identifier_on
FROM sys.databases
```

However, [the SET options can also be set by the client application](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2008/09/09/understanding-sql-server-set-options-2-set-ansi-nulls-on-off.aspx) connecting to SQL Server.

A perfect example is SQL Server Management Studio which has the default values for SET ANSI_NULLS and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER both to ON. This is one of the reasons why I could not initially duplicate the error you posted.

Anyway, to duplicate the error, try this (this will override the SSMS default settings):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON 
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE T1 (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    TypeVal AS ((1)) PERSISTED NOT NULL
)
```

You can fix the test case above by using:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

I would recommend tweaking these two settings in your script before the creation of the table and related indexes.

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to use your post to get this working. Unfortunately, it's a little bit more complex than just adding SET statements because our script is created dynamically using a Visual Studio database project and is frequently automatically re-created from a modified database. There is also a bug that prevents some of these settings from being set in the properties for individual objects. More problems but it will now build.

Comment: This was really useful.
Anyway in my case I had to set the NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT to OFF

Comment: NUMERIC_ROUNDABOUT should be  NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT, but the 6 character edit limits me from fixing this.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for this problem:

1. Go to the Server Properties.
2. Select the *Connections* tab.
3. Check if the **ansi_padding** option is unchecked.

Comment: Those are only database defaults. Settings are usually overridden by the connection and/or SSMS itself.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to create a table from one database to another on MS SQL Server 2012. Right-clicking on a table and selecting **Script Table as > DROP And CREATE To > New Query Editor Window**, following script was created:

```
USE [SAMPLECOMPANY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Departments]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employees]    Script Date: 8/24/2016 9:31:15 PM ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employees]    Script Date: 8/24/2016 9:31:15 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Departments] FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Departments] ([DepartmentID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Departments]
GO
```

However when executing above script it was returning the error:

> SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use
>   with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations.

The Solution I've found: Enabling the settings on the Top of the script like this:

```
USE [SAMPLECOMPANY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employees]    Script Date: 8/24/2016 9:31:15 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Departments]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employees]    Script Date: 8/24/2016 9:31:15 PM ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Departments] FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Departments] ([DepartmentID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Departments]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Also had this same issue.  Using SSMS to right-click create script, made a script which read...    SET ANSI_PADDING ON,  CREATE MyTable, SET ANSI_PADDING OFF, ALTER TABLE indices.   I had to remove the ancillary SET ANSI_PADDING OFF to get my script to execute.  Never seen this before. Why did SSMS script it out in a way that it couldn't execute?

Answer (score 0):

For me, just setting the compatibility level to higher level works fine. To see C.Level :

```
select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = [your_database]
```

Comment: I just get a number as a result. Then what's next or what does that number mean?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that a computed column had been added to the "included columns" of an index.  Later, when an item in that table was updated, the `merge` statement failed with that message. The merge was in a trigger, so this was hard to track down! Removing the computed column from the index fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the filtered index and my inserts and updates were failing. All I did was to change the stored procedure that had the insert and update statement to:

```
create procedure abc
()
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON 
SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error replicating from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012 which as been working for years. Turns out it was a new DDL Trigger I created on the SQL Server 2012. I dropped it. Replication started working again.