# INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect setting only in Perl Sybase

Tags: sybase

I have the following Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $db_connect = 'dbi:Sybase:server=10.2.2.2\CATDB;charset=utf8;database=Dev';
my $db_username = "*****";
my $db_password = "*****";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($db_connect, $db_username, $db_password,{ RaiseError => 1, 
            PrintError => 1, 
            AutoCommit => 1,
            syb_chained_txn => 0, 
            syb_enable_utf8 => 1  } ) || die "Failed to connect to *** database: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $insertContractSQL2 = '
BEGIN
DECLARE @ContractID int
UPDATE dbo.Sequences SET NextContractID = NextContractID + 1
SET @ContractID = (SELECT NextContractID FROM dbo.Sequences)
 
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON, ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF, ARITHIGNORE, CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT, IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS, NOCOUNT, NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT, XACT_ABORT OFF

INSERT INTO dbo.CONTRACTS 
            (ContractID
            ,modifieddate
            ,FranchiseID
            ,FamilyID
            ,EducatorID
            ,StartDate
            ,EndDate
            ,ContractTypeID
            ,PayRate1
            ,PayRate2
            ,PayRate3
            ,PayRate1Hours
            ,PayRate2Hours
            ,PayRate3Hours
            ,WageAdminContractorRate
            ,ContributionContractorRate
            ,WageAdminAmount
            ,ACCAmount
            ,PorseContributionAmount
            ,WINZSubsidyAmount
            ,WINZSubsidyAmountChildcareOSCAR
            ,ACCInvoicedPerQuarterAmount
            ,FamilyAPAmount
            ,OtherFortnightPayment
            ,OtherFortnightPaymentDesc
            ,ReferralAgencyID
            ,NextAppraisalDate
            ,NextAppraisalTypeID
            ,PendingApproval
            ,Active
            ,modifiedby
            ,BeingEdited
            ,MOENetworkID
            ,NewFlag
            ,ReceivedDate
            ,FreeECEAmount
            ,OptionalChargeRate
            ,OptionalChargeAgreement
            ,TerminationApproved
            ,AgreedDeductions
            ,PayRateEce
            ,PayRateEceHours
            ,PreECEClarity
            ,TotalOptionalCharges
            ,NonChildContributionAmount
            ,FreeECETopup
            ,Donation
            ,NonChildWinzChildcareAmount
            ,ManuallyTerminated
            ,ContractDuplicatedFlag
            ,CreateDate
            ,RosteredContractID)
            VALUES (
             @ContractID
            ,GETDATE()
            ,63,22901,9134,\'2014-06-03 00:00:00.0\',\'2014-06-28 00:00:00.0\',2,0,0,0,5,0,0,4.75,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,null,null,null,0,1,\'admin\',1,null,0,\'2014-06-10 00:00:00.0\',0,0,0,0,null,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\'2014-06-03 15:30:15.037\',4)
 
END  
';

 $dbh->do($insertContractSQL2);
```

When it runs I get:

```
/usr/bin/perl test.pl
DBD::Sybase::db do failed: Server message number=1934 severity=16 state=1 
    line=10 server= text=INSERT failed because the
    following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, 
    CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that 
    SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on 
    computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications 
    and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.  
    at test.pl line 89.
```

Now this is a lousy question I know. But I have run the same query via three different GUIs for SQL Server and I don't get this error. I have gone through the first 3 or 4 pages of Google results, and have gotten nowhere. Any information would be much appreciated.

Note: I assume that because the query runs in other tools that set options are correct.

Comment: If you use `SQL Server` please have a look at my answer on [Failed because incorrect arithabort setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140159/failed-because-incorrect-arithabort-setting/35750269#35750269) page. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9235638/257635) you may need to set order to create a table with a persisted, computed column, the following connection settings must be enabled:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

You can set this with the $sth->do() method or with ISQL. You need to execute them first after you connect to the DB, before executing your "SELECT", "UPDATE" or any other command.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is how it should work. However this does not help.

Comment: If you execute insertContractSQL2 statements directly on db do you get any error?

Comment: No I don't get any error there. This missing peice was that the set had to be the first thing executed. Putting this first   $boris_dbh->do(' SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON, ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
     SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF, ARITHIGNORE, CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT, IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS, NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT  , NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF'); fixed it.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, SET should be the first thing after you connect to DB.

Comment: Now I have a simple example that works. But when I try to do the same thing in the real code it breaks. This is not my day...

Comment: Do you use same `$dbh` throughout the script or do you connect again at some place in real code? Or is there any other module which does this and you're not aware of?

Comment: Same $dbh, the only difference is a prepare a few statements before running the query.

Comment: I gave up and now use a separate db handle for the query that has issues. This works but is nasty. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in this nasty way:

```
EXEC('
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE Name = ''IX_GPS_XY'') 
        DROP INDEX [IX_GPS_XY] ON [dbo].[Cities];
')
EXEC('
    INSERT INTO dbo.Cities(Name, CountyID, GPSXY) 
    VALUES...
')
EXEC('
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE Name = ''IX_GPS_XY'') BEGIN
        SET ARITHABORT ON;
        ...
        CREATE SPATIAL INDEX...
')
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran a script generated by SQL Server studio and had the error "INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'"

My solution is to add the keyword "GO" and the script worked.

The script with error:

```
--SOME INSERT STATEMENTS
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

--SOME INSERT STATEMENTS
```

The script that worked:

```
--SOME INSERT STATEMENTS
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
--SOME INSERT STATEMENTS
```

I hope it helps.