# Restoring SQL Server 2014 database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2014, database-restore

I am trying to restore a SQL Server 2014 database in SQL Server 2005. I am doing by generating the complete script (with schema and data) from SQL Server 2014.

I get an error saying

> 'INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or query notifications and/or xml data type methods.'

and

> 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'T_GASAdminNote' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.'

I have searched for solution but have not been able to rectify the problem. I have tried the solution given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235527/incorrect-set-options-error-when-building-database-project), but it didn't help me.

Can anyone suggest me some solutions for restoring the database.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** sorry - misread your question...

The first error means just that - for some operation you're trying to do, your `SET ANSI_PADDING` setting is wrong. Read the [official documentation on ANSI_PADDING on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) to learn more about this setting. Check what your setting is now - obviously, if that error occurs, you need the other setting for that operation you're attempting to do.

The second error means that your table `T_GASAdminNote` has an `identity` column, and you're trying to insert values into that column, but *without* first enabling this by using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT T_GASAdminNote ON` (and don't forget to *disable* the option after you're done!)

Comment: I generated scripts  and i got those errors while running the script

Comment: That can happen. It's always a good idea to review generated scripts before running them.