# SQL Special character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query where I need to find the ' character.

Like Shivam's - I need to find the ' mark.

```
select * from DTCountries where CountryCode like '%'%'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in sqlserver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double it up

```
select * from DTCountries where CountryCode like '%''%'
```

Answer (score 11):

Just need to escape it.

```
SELECT * FROM DTCountries WHERE CountryCode LIKE '%''%'
```

Comment: The other answer was accepted even though mine came in first (beat him by a whole second... lol), but I still appreciate the Upvotes everyone's been giving. And, yes, seems like a dupe question.