# Declare string in quote in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a SQL command but I am getting error message of **Not a Valid Identifier**.

If I am using this command,

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell N'mkdir C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Backup\1042012'
GO
```

then this command works properly

But, if I am using this command

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate varchar(50)
DECLARE @Path varchar(200)
DECLARE @Command varchar(200)

SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE()
SET @Path = N'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Backup'
SET @Command = N'xp_cmdshell " ' + 'MKDIR' + ' '+ @Path + '\' +  @CurrentDate + '" '

EXEC @Command
GO
```

I am getting that error message. Is something to do with declaring a string properly or not.

Comment: To assist your troubleshooting, you can issue a SELECT @Command instead of EXEC to see what the string looks like that you are building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that : is not allowed in directory names, I converted it to a string but it doesn't have the time on it:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate varchar(50)
DECLARE @Path varchar(200)
DECLARE @Command varchar(200)

SET @CurrentDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 110)
SET @Path = N'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Backup'
SET @Command = 'MKDIR' + ' '+ @Path + '\' +  @CurrentDate
PRINT @Command
EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command
```

Comment: 3 years later and still very helpful! :)  I can never quite get the quotes right when setting up command line variables.

Answer (score 7):

I've added `EXEC`, a unicode identifier (`N`), and [single quotes in place of your double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sqlserver).  Please let us know how this works.

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate varchar(50)
DECLARE @Path varchar(200)
DECLARE @Command varchar(200)

SET @CurrentDate = convert(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)
SET @Path = N'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Backup'
SET @Command = N'EXEC xp_cmdshell N''' + 'MKDIR' + ' '+ @Path + '\' +  @CurrentDate + ''''

EXEC (@Command)
GO
```

**UPDATE**

Testing revealed the need for formatting the date to `yyyymmdd` ([other formats available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)) and also parenthesis around `EXEC` as always (thanks, @Lamak).  This gives us the following directory, today:

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Backup\20121004
```

As an aside, I do recommend this date format as it will sort alphabetically in chronological order in your filesystem, whereas `mmddyyyy` or `ddmmyyyy` would not.

Comment: don't `EXEC` needs parentheses to execute a string?

Comment: @TimLehner: I am getting this error message Could not find stored procedure 'EXEC xp_cmdshell N'MKDIR C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Backup\Oct  4 2012  1:25PM''.

Comment: Please try this most recent version. I've even tested it as-is on my own server (yes, I definitely should've done that first!).