# use parameter in where which contain ' with select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to use select query in SQL Server 2008 in which I want to search book's details according to their name.

I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM MasterTitle 
WHERE BookName = '"+s1''
```

and it works fine but problem occurs when `s1` contains a quote `'`

Something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM MasterTitle 
WHERE BookName = 'Educational Cd'S (Set)' and DisplayAuthorName = 'Test'
```

I can't use escape character

Comment: *Exact duplicate*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586588/1563422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MasterTitle
WHERE BookName = 'Educational Cd'+char(39)+'S ( Set)' 
     and DisplayAuthorName ='Test'
```

Comment: I cant use char(39) in middle of d string. because i used a parameter like 's1' for book name and it is entered by the user..and s1 may contain ' or may not.

Comment: you mean you use query like following: <pre>select * from MasterTitle where BookName = @s1</pre>, do you? because I don't understand how you use the s1 in your query; if you use BookName=@s1, then even you @s1 has ', it doesn't matter

Comment: but if you use a dynamic sql construction, like sql = sql + s1, then if s1 has ' inside, it can cause problem, then you need to use escape, like replace(s1, char(39), char(39)+char(39))