# How to insert special characters to a table row via SQL Editor

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in my SQL Server database with a column of type `nvarchar(50)`;

I tried to do this:

1. Right click on my table
2. Selecting "Edit 200 first rows"
3. Typing in that column 'a'

I get an error like this:

> Error source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
>   Error message: Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
>   Correct the errors and retry".

Why do I get this error message and how can I fix this?

Comment: There is NO circumstance in which you should be adding or changing records this way. If you need changes to data they should alawys be done thorough sql scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used aqua data studio and tested this it is allowing me.

my result:::

```
 id     testc     
 -----  --------- 
 1      'asdfasd'
```

If you want to use it thrugh .net then while passing the string add the escape sequences. suppose if you are sending "'"--single quote.. then send I have used and tested this it like "\'" is allowing me.

refer below link:::

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/157918/How-can-I-insert-a-special-character-in-sql-server

Comment: doesn't backslash escape ? so it should be "\'" ?

Comment: can you give an exapmle of what to type in the editor in order to get the word 'a' inserted?

Comment: you can use aqua data studio.I have tested and it is allowing me directly without changing anything.

Comment: OK, but in sql server managment studio 2008 - what do you type? Please write each character you type.

Comment: check this link:::  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error.
I want to insert a value `I am Nam 'ABC'` into `MyTable` at field `Description` as following SQL statement

```
Insert Into table MyTable (Description) values('I am Nam 'ABC'');
```

Once `Insert` command executed the error occur immediately

> Incorrect syntax near 'ABC'.

Note that the reason why is SQL will understand character `" ' "` which before `ABC` belongs to character
 `" ' "` before `I`, and one after ABC belongs to `" ' "` at the end. As a result `ABC` does not belong to SQL 
statement anymore therefore it makes a break of statement.

Here is my solution:
I added two single quotes for each side of `ABC`

```
Insert Into table MyTable (Description) values('I am Nam ' 'ABC' ' ');
```