# sql stored procedure single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure as below

```
create procedure TestTry

BEGIN
declare @query varchar(max)
SET NOCOUNT ON;   

set @query = 'select * from table1 when RECORD_FLAG <> 't' 
then Convert(Decimal(10,4),ISNULL(T.HISTORY_PCR ,0))  else '0'';

exec (@query)
end
```

Here after RECORD_FLAG <> I want to give it in single quotes and also give 0 in single quotes how to give that

The above shown is a sample in real time my query is big I have to give the query in @query only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586588/2998271

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use '' (double) for ' (single)

```
set @query = 'select * from table1 when RECORD_FLAG <> ''t'' 
then Convert(Decimal(10,4),ISNULL(T.HISTORY_PCR ,0))  else ''0''';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure TestTry
AS       --<-- you'er also missing AS key word here
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
 declare @query varchar(max)


 set @query = 'select * from table1 when RECORD_FLAG <> ''t'' 
              then Convert(Decimal(10,4),ISNULL(T.HISTORY_PCR ,0))  else ''0''';

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @query      --<-- use this syntax to execute dynamic sql 
end
```

> Also you do not need to use dynamic sql for such a simple query,
>   dynamic sql is the devil of sql and you want to avoid using it
>   whenever possible.

**Your Query**

Also your query syntax isnt right you are trying to execute a query as follows

```
select * 
from table1 
when RECORD_FLAG <> 't'   --<-- cant use WHEN without the CASE statement also you
                             --cannot use a Case statement here right after your table name
```