# SQL insert into database with apostrophe

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am running a program on classic ASP and inserting into a database with the following:

```
CreateJob.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Jobs (JobID, CompanyName, DateReceived, DateOfDocument, ClientReference, Subject, TypeOfService,DueDate,AssignedAgent, ClientName, Plaintiff, Defendant1, Defendant2, Defendant3, CourtJurisdiction, Court, Subtype, CourtNumber, Amount, ServiceMethod, JobNotes, JobStatus, CreatedBy, CreatedDate)  VALUES (" & Request.Form("jobid") & ", '""" & Request.Form("compname") & """', '" & Request.Form("datereceived") & "','" & Request.Form("dateofdoc") & "', '" & Request.Form("clientref") & "', '" & Request.Form("subjects") & "', '" & Request.Form("TypeOfService") & "', '" & Request.Form("duedate") & "', '" & Request.Form("AssignedAgent") & "', '" & Request.Form("ClientName") & "', '" & Request.Form("Plaintiff") & "', '" & Request.Form("Defendant1") & "', '" & Request.Form("Defendant2") & "', '" & Request.Form("Defendant3") & "', '" & Request.Form("CourtJurisdiction") & "', '""" &  Request.Form("Court") & """', '" & Request.Form("SubType") & "', '" & Request.Form("CourtNumber") & "', '" & Request.Form("Amount") & "','" & Request.Form("ServiceMethod") & "','" & Request.Form("JobNotes") & "', 'OPEN', '" & Session("LoggedName") & "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) "
```

However, if one of the value has an apostrophe, the program crashes and I am not sure how to escape it.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sqlserver

Comment: Escaping apostrophes is one of the many good reasons to use query parameters.

Comment: @ipohfly That method is fine for SQL based usage, but the OP is using this from code in [tag:asp-classic] and pointing him to answers like this is just going to lead him down the wrong path. We should be suggesting parameterising his inputs using the `ADODB.Command` object in [tag:ado].

Comment: @Lankymart apologies as i did not take note of the mentioning of ASP usage there. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: You could replace the single apostrophe with double apostrophe and insert the record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace isn't the way to go here, you are already using a `ADODB.Command` object so why not use a [parameterised query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Try this;

As you haven't provided information on your field types I can only speculate so instead I've added `[datatype]` and `[size]` placeholders for you to replace with [ADO data type constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675318(v=vs.85).aspx). A good resource for how data types in T-SQL map to [ado](/questions/tagged/ado) is this article - [Data Type Mapping](http://carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx)

```vb
sql = ""
sql = sql & "INSERT INTO dbo.Jobs (" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "JobID, CompanyName, DateReceived, DateOfDocument, ClientReference" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & ", Subject, TypeOfService,DueDate,AssignedAgent, ClientName, Plaintiff" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & ", Defendant1, Defendant2, Defendant3, CourtJurisdiction, Court" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & ", Subtype, CourtNumber, Amount, ServiceMethod, JobNotes, JobStatus" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & ", CreatedBy, CreatedDate" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"

With CreateJob
    .ActiveConnection = "yourconnectionstring"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = sql
    'Add your parameters (all 24 of them in order)
    'Assumed JobID is int which equates to adInteger ADO data type constant.
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@JobID", adInteger, adParamInput, 4))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@CompanyName", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@DateReceived", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@DateOfDocument", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@ClientReference", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Subject", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@TypeOfService", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@DueDate", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@AssignedAgent", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@ClientName", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Plaintiff", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Defendant1", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Defendant2", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Defendant3", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@CourtJurisdiction", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Court", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Subtype", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@CourtNumber", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Amount", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@ServiceMethod", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@JobNotes", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@JobStatus", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@CreatedBy", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@CreatedDate", [datatype], adParamInput, [size]))

    'Specify your parameter values may need some conversion based on what you are passing.
    .Parameters("@JobId").Value = Request.QueryString("jobid")
    'Add the other 23 parameters as the above line.
    '...

    'Doing an INSERT no need to return recordset
    Call .Execute(adExecuteNoRecords)
End With
Set CreateJob = Nothing
```