# Insert into db, Object Required String

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, asp-classic

I need to insert some data into DB, there is a problem..it gives me an error :

Source line:

```vb
SET sql ="Insert Into Products (ProductName,SupID,CatID,Price,Pic,Description) Values( '"&pName&"','"&pbId&"','"&pcId&"','"&price&"','"&pic&"','"&desc&"')"
```

> Description: Object required: '[string: "Insert Into Products"]'

I dont understand what he wants..

This is my code:

```vb
dim sql
dim price
dim desc
dim pName
dim pcId
dim pbId
dim pic
set pic = Request.Form("picUpload")
set desc = Request.Form("tbDescProduct")
set price= Request.Form("tbPriceProduct")
set pcId =Request.Form("ddlCategoryForProd")
set pbId =Request.Form("ddlBrandForProd")
set pName=Request.Form("tbProductName")
IF((bName<>"")AND(desc<>"")AND(price<>"")AND(pcId<>"-1")AND(pbId<>"-1")AND (pic<>"")) THEN

set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("WebData/DB.mdb") & ";"  
set rs = con.Execute("Select * FROM Products WHERE ProductName = '"&pName&"' and mode= true")
IF rs.EOF = true then           
  SET sql ="Insert Into Products (ProductName,SupID,CatID,Price,Pic,Description) Values( '"&pName&"','"&pbId&"','"&pcId&"','"&price&"','"&pic&"','"&desc&"')"
  SET rs =con.Execute(sql)
  response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Product added succesfully!');</script>") 
ELSE
  response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Product already exist!');</script>") 
END IF

'END IF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBScript, VBA and VB5/6, `SET` is required to assign an object reference; to assign any other sort of data (including a string), just remove it:

```
sql = "Insert Into Products (ProductName,SupID,CatID,Price,Pic,Description) Values( '"&pName&"','"&pbId&"','"&pcId&"','"&price&"','"&pic&"','"&desc&"')"
```

(In VBA and VB5/6 you could also use `LET` here.)

The reason `SET` works when assigning the result of a `Request.Form("foo")` call is because the `Form` collection is a collection of objects - the subsequent tests against `""` and `"-1"` are valid only because the objects returned have a default parameterless property or method that return a string-compatible variant.

Comment: If that solved your problem, could you mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Didn't notice the `Set` on the form collection good catch. +1 Still other issues with the code though, especially if you're storing foreign keys as strings, not to mention the vulnerability to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

If I was to guess I'd say your problem is you're passing the `SupID` and `CatID` fields as strings when they are probably integers. The problem with handling INSERT this way is you leave yourself open to SQL Injection plus you encounter data type issues like you seem to be experiencing here.

Whenever possible when interacting with a database you should try to use Parameterised Queries. In Classic ASP the best object to do this is `ADODB.Command`.

Here is an example using your code;

> **NOTE:** If you have problems with the ADO named constants like `adParamInput` then look in the links section below to see how to use the `METADATA` tag in your `global.asa` file to reference the ADO type library across your application.

```vb
Dim cmd, sql, conn_string, rs, data

'Wouldn't recommend storing your database inside your website root, instead
'store it outside in another folder and set up a variable in an include file
'to store the location. That way it is not accessible to everyone.
conn_string = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("WebData/DB.mdb") & ";"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName = ?"
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = conn_string
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = sql
  Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@ProductName", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))
  Set rs = .Execute(, Array(pName))
  If Not rs.EOF Then data = rs.GetRows()
  Call rs.Close()
  Set rs = Nothing
End With

If IsArray(data) Then
  sql = ""
  sql = sql & "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, SupID, CatID, Price, Pic, Description) " & vbCrLf
  sql = sql & "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

  Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn_string
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = sql
    'Define Parameters
    'Making some assumptions about your data types, but you can modify these to fit
    'good guide for this is http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@ProductName", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@SupID", adInteger, adParamInput, 4))
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@CatID", adInteger, adParamInput, 4))
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Price", adCurrency, adParamInput, 4))
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Pic", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255))
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Description", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 1000))
    'Some of your variables may require conversion before setting the parameter values.
    .Parameters("@ProductName").Value = pName
    .Parameters("@SupID").Value = CLng(pbId)
    .Parameters("@CatID").Value = CLng(pcId)
    .Parameters("@Price").Value = price
    .Parameters("@Pic").Value = pic
    .Parameters("@Description").Value = desc

    'Execute Command
    .Execute()
  End With
  Set cmd = Nothing
  Call Response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Product added succesfully!');</script>")
Else
  Call Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Product already exist!');</script>") 
End If
```

**Links**

- [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx)
- [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml)
- [Answer from SQL insert into database with apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22037613/692942)