# How to upload a file and insert a statement into the database at the same time

Tags: mysql, file-upload, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I'm having problems uploading a file and inserting data into the database at the same time. 
It's written in classic ASP

```vb
 Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
 Upload.OverwriteFiles = False
 Upload.Save Server.MapPath("files/drawings/")

 sql = "Insert into Name(first,last) values ("'" & Request.form("firstname") & "','" & Request.form("lastname") & "' " )
 ADOConn.Execute sql
```

Comment: Are you sure, you haven't got a typo in `Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")`? And no user named O'Brian or some such too?

Comment: if i should comment out the upload statements the insert statement works and if i should comment out the insert statement the upload works. But with both together it doesn't work!

Comment: @VMai The `Persists.Upload` ProgId is correct it refers to the [Persits Software Upload COM Component known as ASPUpload](http://www.aspupload.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is when you perform the upload your dealing with the request as binary, which invalidates the `Request.Form` collection (same as if you call `Request.BinaryRead()`. To counter this the ASPUpload component provides a [`Form` Collection](http://www.aspupload.com/object_upload.html#Form) of it's own which contains the posted form values.

Changing the values `Request.Form` to `Upload.Form` should fix the problem in this case.

```vb
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
Upload.OverwriteFiles = False
Upload.Save Server.MapPath("files/drawings/")

'Also make sure the string concatenation is correct (had extra " in after "values")
sql = "Insert into Name(first,last) values ('" & Upload.Form("firstname") & "','" & Upload.Form("lastname") & "' " )
ADOConn.Execute sql
```

> **WARNING** The above code snippet is not sanitized and open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), consider using the `ADODB.Command` object to parametrise the query before execution (*some assumptions about data type and size have been made*).
>
> *Quick Example*
>
> ```vb
>  Dim cmd, conn, sql
>
>  conn = "your connection string"
>  'Parametrised query
>  sql = "Insert into Name(first,last) values (?, ?)"
>
>  Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
>  With cmd
>    'No need to pass ADODB.Connection pass connection string and
>    'the ADODB.Command will do it for you.
>    .ActiveConnection = conn
>    .CommandType = adCmdText
>    .CommandText = sql
>    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("first", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 100))
>    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("last", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 100))
>    'Not returning any records just inserting
>    Call .Execute(adExecuteNoRecords)
>  End With
>  'Clean-up
>  Set cmd = Nothing
> ```

- [Answer to SQL insert into database with apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22037613/692942)

---

> **On a side note:**
>
> This information isn't hard to find the ASPUpload [Object Reference](http://www.aspupload.com/objectreference.html) and [Online User Manual](http://www.aspupload.com/manual.html) are very good. In fact if you had looked at the [Section 2.2 - FILES and FORM Collections](http://www.aspupload.com/manual_simple.html#2_2) you would have had the answer to your question without posting here.
>
> Personal experience has taught me that when dealing with 3rd Party COM Components 9/10 times the supporting documentation is very good, especially so in the case of [Persits Software](http://www.persits.com/) components.