# Executing stored procedure of SQL in VBScript

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

There is a stored procedure in SQL server which takes four values (2 `datetime`and 2 `varchar`) as input and returns `int` value as output. This stored Procedure is working fine in SQL Server. In VBScript code of Classic ASP application, I've made some connections and trying to get the `int` output value of Stored procedure and Print on web page. The below is the code..

```vb
 dim DD 'This variable stores output of the Stored Procedure date_diff
 dim CS
 CS = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Data Source=BLAHBLAH; InitialCatalog=BLAH; User Id=BLAH; Pwd=BLAH"
 dim objConn
 dim objRS1
 dim StoredProc1
 storedProc1 = "exec date_diff ' "& R1("LEAVE_FROM") &" ' , ' "& R1("LEAVE_TO") &" ' ,'"R2("COMPANY_CODE")"','"R2("LOCATION_CODE")"' ,'" & DD &"' output"

 Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objConn.CommandTimeout = 60
 objConn.Open CS

 objRS1.CursorLocation = 3
 objRS1.CursorType = 3 
 objRS1.Open StoredProc1, objConn

 If  not objRS1.EOF Then
    response.write  DD 'Printing the output of SP here
 end if
```

I am not getting 500 - Internal Server error on the web page. Can you Please guide where am I going wrong..?

Comment: There are plenty of resources on [so] about this exact problem already. See [Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21944948/692942) and [How to use ASP variables in SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20702205/692942) and [Change stored proc to inline sql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36127333/692942). Key thing here is **don't use the `ADODB.Connection` object to execute Stored Procedures** use the `ADODB.Command` object that it what it is there for.

Comment: That way you don't leave yourself open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because the `ADODB.Command` object builds [parametrised queries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/) that provides a level of protection that `objRS1.Open StoredProc1, objConn` doesn't when you pass variables directly into the SQL statement.

Comment: Hi Lankymart...in the post I've seen your reply.. `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@userinumber ", 200, 1, 10, inumber)` what does the `200`, `1`,`10`, `inumber` refer to..

Comment: They refer to the numeric values of [ADO constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678353(v=vs.85).aspx) that are not accessible by name until you `#include` `adovbs.asp` *(not recommended)* or you use `METADATA` tag to add a reference to the Type Library allowing you to call the actually named constants. For example `200` is `adVarChar`. See [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26776169/692942) explains how to implement it.

Comment: Hi Lankymart...I am getting error for this small code...Do you find any error in this..??
`Dim conn_string`
`conn_string = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=SCRBNGADK001988;database=SMART2UAT;UId=conapt;Pwd=conapt"`

`cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")`
        
`cmd.ActiveConnection = conn_string`

Comment: `cmd` is an object so has to be `Set`, should be `Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")` you probably got an error similar to `Object not found or With block variable not set`.

Comment: U r exactly correct bro.....