# Classic asp - editing and saving a record?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I am working on a school front-end system called iSAMS, which uses classic asp, using SQL Server 2008 R2.

In the simplest terms, my main asp page (viewstudent-edit-test.asp) returns and displays two fields from a database table : **txtCommentID** (the Report ID) and **txtComment** (the actual report). It looks something like this :

```
ReportID    Report
--------    ------
32          Good progress, now please edit me ...
```

I (or the user) need to be able to edit the data in the **Report** column, and at the moment, when the **Report** field is clicked on, the text becomes editable.

when the "**Submit**" button is clicked, it fires off another page called **updateform.asp**, and this is where the problem is.

It returns the error on **updateform.asp** :

```
Error page: /legacy/custommodules/ucasreports/updateform.asp
Error category: adodb.command
Error type: arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range,
or are in conflict with one another.
Error source: 
Error line: 9
```

...and the line 9 is in updateform.asp (1st **sqlProp.Parameters** line):

```
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="ACN.asp"-->
<%
getConID = request.form("ID")
getCom = request.form("Comment")

Set sqlProp=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 sqlProp.ActiveConnection=Conn
  sqlProp.commandtext="update CAN_Tbl_UCAS_Reports set txtComment=? where
     txtCommentID=?"
'--------------
  sqlProp.Parameters.Append sqlProp.CreateParameter("@txtComment", adVarChar,
   adParamInput, 3500, getCom)
'--------------       
  sqlProp.Parameters.Append sqlProp.CreateParameter("@txtCommentID",
   adInteger, adParamInput, , getConID)
   sqlProp.Execute
%>
```

My original page code which displays the data : (viewstudent-edit-test.asp) :

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT txtSchoolID, txtID, SubjectTeacher, txtCommentID,
 txtComment FROM CAN_Tbl_UCAS_Reports WHERE intReportType = 1 AND 
  txtSchoolID = " & paramBuilder.NextParameter(intID) & " ORDER BY txtID"

Set rsRecord = Database.GetRs(sql, conn, paramBuilder.Parameters)

if not rsRecord.EOF then
  do until rsRecord.EOF

'First we need to create our Variables
  ConID = rsRecord("txtCommentID")
  Com = rsRecord("txtComment")
%>
<tr>
 <td style="text-align:center"><%Response.Write(rsRecord.Fields
  ("txtCommentID").value)%></td>

 <td><%Response.Write(rsRecord.Fields("txtComment").value)%></td>
  <td style="text-align:center">
   <form action="updateform.asp" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ID" value="<%=ConID%>" />
     <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="Comment"><%=Com%></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Subsdfmit" />
       </form>
  </td>
</tr>
<%
rsRecord.Movenext 
 loop
  end if

  rsRecord.close
  set rsRecord = nothing 
%>
```

Finally, my connection string file, ACN.asp :

```
<%
Dim Conn
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data
 Source=sourcebob;UID=userbob;PWD=passwordbob;DATABASE=iBOB;"
Conn.Open
%>
```

I have checked the type and order of the parameters, and they seem to be OK. Googling the error message points to a missing connection string, but that is not the problem. It seems there are many examples of forms where user input is accepted, but not how to successfully edit pre-existing data.

Apologies for so much code, but I thought it was need in order to analyse the problem. Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use ADODB Named Constants you have to either declare them *(include the common `adovbs.asp`)* or in your `global.asa` file *(which will be located in the ASP Web Application root folder)* add a [`METADATA` declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35530750/692942) to allow the type library to be automatically available to any page inside the ASP Web Application.

Comment: Thanks, Lankymart. After adding an include statement for the file adovbs_inc, asp, everything worked fine.

The content of this fie can be found here : 

http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/code/adovbs.txt

Comment: You are better off using the [`METADATA` method](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/ASPScripts/PrintPage.asp?REF=%2Fwebtech%2F110199-1.shtml), it doesn't require being added via an `#include` and if added to the `global.asa` inside a ASP Web Application it applies to all pages.

Comment: Thanks again, Lankymart. Sorry for the delay in replying - for some reason I have only just got your notification.