# Parameterized query in VBScript referring OracleDB

Tags: oracle, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a parameterized query which is giving

> "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" error.

```vb
Dim Conn
Dim Cmd
Dim RS

Dim strID
Dim param

strID = Request.QueryString("id") 
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open strConnect    


Set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")


Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE (id = :id)"
Set param = Cmd.CreateParameter("id", adVarChar , adParamInput ,50 , strID)
Cmd.Parameters.Append param
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

Set Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn


Set RS = Cmd.Execute()
```

I'm trying to modify in syntax in several ways, then it is giving

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Please help me to get out of this. For your information, there is no problem with connection as i am able to connect with normal query.

Comment: Admittedly, I don't use Oracle but is the provider syntax any different then other ADODB providers when using `adCmdText`? Have you tried `?` instead of `:id` in your SQL string?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm not sure about the syntax.  I have tried `?` as suggested but still facing "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" error

Comment: Just to confirm, you tried `Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE (id = ?)"` without success?

Comment: Yes, @Lankymart

Comment: @Lankymart , Can you please help me to get out of this.

Comment: As I don't use Oracle myself the best I can do is point you to [a wealth of information on that exact error on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB725GB725&q=ORA-01008%3A+not+all+variables+bound+adodb&oq=ORA-01008%3A+not+all+variables+bound+adodb&gs_l=psy-ab.3...195830.197739.0.198039.6.6.0.0.0.0.142.592.4j2.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.509...0j0i67k1j0i22i30k1j33i21k1j33i160k1.0.1hzZUjewr0w).

Comment: Hopefully one of the many suggestions will help you find the cause, the problem is the error can have umpteen causes from fields not being nullable to a corrupt index on a table.

Answer (score 0):

a few things to check:

1) try hard coding a value for strID, so instead of:

```
strID = Request.QueryString("id")
```

try

```
strID = 100
```

2) double check your column definitions and make sure you're selecting from a varchar(50) field

3) make sure you have adovbs.inc referenced on your page for the ADO constants definitions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Lankymart, luckily i got solution for this as below. It is working fine for me and sorry for the delay in posting the answer,  my issue resolved 2 hours ago.

```
Dim Conn
Dim Cmd
Dim RS

Dim strID
Dim param

strID = Request.QueryString("id") 
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open strConnect    
Set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With Cmd
.CommandText = "SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE id = ?"
.Parameters.Append  .CreateParameter(,200, 1 ,50 ,strID)
 Set .ActiveConnection = Conn
End With

Set RS = Cmd.Execute()
```

Comment: As Josh [mentions at point 3.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428521/692942), it will be the lack of the named constants like `adCmdText`, `adVarChar` etc being defined. I didn't mention it though because it should have caused an error before reaching Oracle, because `Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText` I would also have expected it to fail. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530750/692942) for how to solve it using METADATA without having to remove the named constants.