# Using SQL parameters returns "Arguments are of the wrong type"

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am having some trouble figuring out how to write classic ASP queries to prevent SQL injection.

I have read a few posts on it and have come up with the following script;

```vb
set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

SQL = "Select * From tablename Where Email Like ? And Deleted=0"

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = qText
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandTimeout = 900
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@name", adVarchar, adParamInput, 50, "%" & this.Form("email") & "%")

Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Every time i run it though, i am getting the following error;

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
```

I have followed the instructions from here https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/classic-asp-sql-injection-prevention-by-using-query-parameter/

Any help figuring this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you including the ADO constant definitions? (i.e. adovbs.inc)

Comment: @Diado No im not sure what that is to be honest, im trying to learn as im doing it. Can i change the SQL statement to a stored procedure?

Comment: `SQL = "Select * From tablename Where Email Like @name And Deleted=0"` - does changing the sql help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADODB.Parameters error '800a0e7c' Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511870/adodb-parameters-error-800a0e7c-parameter-object-is-improperly-defined-incons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`adVarchar`, `adCmdText` and `adParamInput` are constant values that need to be defined before they can be used. There are a number of ways you can do this:

1. Define just the constants you require manually:

   ```
   const adVarChar = 200
   const adParamInput = &H0001
   const adCmdText = &H0001
   ```
2. Use the values directly (this is less readable / maintable and generally not recommended):

   ```
   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@name", 200, &H0001, 50, "%" & this.Form("email") & "%")
   ```
3. Include a `adovbs.inc` which defines all of the ADO constants in a handy include file:

   ```
    <!--#include virtual="/adovbs.inc"-->
   ```

   The adovbs.inc file itself is available for download in lots of places on the web (make sure you give it a quick scan to check it doesn't include anything nasty), the [4GuysFromRolla site](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513005432/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/faq/Beginner/faq7.shtml) being a popular one (download the `.txt` linked and rename it to `.inc`)
4. Include a [reference to the ADO TypeLib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525469(v=vs.90).aspx):

   ```
   <!--metadata type="TypeLib" name="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" uuid="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}" version="2.8"-->
   ```

Comment: cmd.CommandText = qText this is the line that seems to be erroring now

Comment: You're storing your query text in a variable called `SQL`, not `qText`, as far as I can tell. Therefore you need `cmd.CommandText = SQL`

Comment: Ok, that one worked ... Last one i promise hahaha now this line is erroring cmd.CommandType = adCmdTxt ... Sorry to be annoying, im really new at this obviously

Comment: I missed that one - same issue as the others, it needs to be defined. I've added the definition to my answer :)

Comment: Opps, my bad hahaha i missed the e in text ... IT WORKS PERFECT!! Thank you so much for your help, its really appreciated.

Comment: BTW, you can use those constants without defining them manually by including a reference to the ADODB type library in your ASP page. This is done using a metadata tag: `<!--metadata type="TypeLib" name="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" uuid="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}" version="2.8"-->` - compare ["Using Type Libraries in ASP Pages" on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525469(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Good shout @Tomalak, I had forgotten about the typelib - have added it to the answer :)

Comment: One more tip - the correct GUID can be found out from the registry (search inside `HKLM\Classes\TypeLib`).

Comment: Been [here before multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530750/692942), not like ADODB is an emerging technology. Another dup to add to the pile.