# SQL Statement Not returning correct data

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am trying to alter a SQL statement That is used by a recordset.

The original code works however I need to take out all parts that reference Column and Row numbers as I want to now set the layout of the page differently.

Here is the original query which works however as stated do not want data relating to Columns or Rows anymore

```
select *, (select displayTitle from performance_Dic_Groups where id = '"&rs("groupid")&"') as Dtitle, (SELECT title FROM Performance_Dic_Columns WHERE (GrpID = '" & rs("groupid")& "') AND (inactivedate IS NULL) AND columnnr = (Performance_Dic_Layout2.columnid)) AS Title, (SELECT Rated FROM Performance_Dic_Columns WHERE (Inactivedate IS NULL) AND (GrpID = '" & rs("groupid")& "') AND columnnr = (Performance_Dic_Layout2.columnid)) AS Rated from Performance_Dic_Layout2 where (GrpID='" & rs("groupid") & "')  and ( row='" & c &"' )
```

I have edited it to this

```
select *, (select displayTitle from performance_Dic_Groups where id = '"&rs("groupid")&"') as Dtitle, (SELECT title FROM Performance_Dic_Columns WHERE (GrpID = '" & rs("groupid")& "')) AS Title, (SELECT Rated FROM Performance_Dic_Columns WHERE (Inactivedate IS NULL) AND (GrpID = '" & rs("groupid")& "')) AS Rated from Performance_Dic_Layout2 where (GrpID='" & rs("groupid") & "')
```

What is strange is If I run this new query against my DB it returns fine(Only 1 Row of the correct data) Obviously changing the ID's that are inserted by recordset to 1

So If I run the following in SQL

```
select *, (select displayTitle from performance_Dic_Groups where id = '1') as Dtitle, (SELECT title FROM Performance_Dic_Columns WHERE (GrpID = '1')) AS Title, (SELECT Rated FROM Performance_Dic_Columns WHERE (Inactivedate IS NULL) AND (GrpID = '1')) AS Rated from Performance_Dic_Layout2 where (GrpID='1')
```

It works as expected

I would like the statement to not return data relating to columns and rows

I receive this error in my browser when using the recordset

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Sorry If this is badly Formatted.
Any help Greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using classical ASP, I guess?

Comment: Hi Stefano, Yeh I am

Comment: Skip the sub-queries, do LEFT JOIN's instead.

Comment: Will give that a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

this error means that one of your subqueries is returning more than one result, which means that the value of `groupId` once using recordset returns more than one record.

another thing (just a remark don't know if it's accurate) is that you have spaces in your variable  `'" & rs("groupid")& "'` that should be removed `'"&rs("groupid")&"'`

Comment: Will investigate the subquery, and touch that up, Thanks bugsb

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Classical ASP
You should not build a query string as a literal, but use sql parameters instead. Have a look to [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types) and here for a [VB sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321516/using-sql-parameters-in-asp-classic-object-improperly-defined-error)