# Cannot insert text having ' (apostrophe) into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to insert text into a SQL table using a textbox:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Book(Title) VALUES ('" + textBoxTitle.Text + "','" +
"')", conn);
```

But if text contains apostrophe (ex. You'll...), it's showing:
`Incorrect syntax near 'll'.`

Comment: Why is there a comma after the value and before the closing?

Comment: Don't put values directly into SQL statements.  Use parameters instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have two values in your `VALUES` part. One is `textBoxTitle.Text` and the other one is `''`. But you provided just one column.

If that's true, you should delete `''` part in your query. But more important, you should *always* use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

If parameterized queries and statements creates any problem with single quote, use double single quotes for each.

- [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sqlserver)

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and commands.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Book(Title) VALUES (@title)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", textBoxTitle.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative if you are programming .Net you can use SqlBulkCopy to insert your data without escaping any characters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

As a bonus it is fast (faster than INSERT if you have a lot to insert).