# Check string with special character in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I am having query for fetching values from table like

```
Select email from cust Where name = " John carter's "
```

i am getting error due to single quotation in string....

please help me for the above problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Select email from cust Where name = " John carter''s"
```

Comment: If i have this type of query then Select email from cust Where name = 'John carter's'

Comment: @user3656418 in that case, add only an other `'` before your second single quote like this: `Select email from cust Where name = " John carter''s''" `

Answer (score 0):

if this is something you just need to get right now...

```
Select email from cust Where name LIKE "%John carter%"
```

or you can escape the apostrophe:

```
Select email from cust Where name = " John carter''s"
```

Comment: If i have this type of query then Select email from cust Where name = 'John carter's'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the escape character?

Like this

```
Select email from cust Where name = " John carter''s "
```

Comment: If i have this type of query then Select email from cust Where name = 'John carter's'

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is caused by the fact that (depending on which database program you're using) the single quote `'` is a SQL data-modelling language (DML) delimiter, so the SQL parser may not be able to properly handle it.