# SQL query gives an error, but looks fine

Tags: php, sql-server

So, here's the query (copied and pasted from browser, echoed directly from the php code.)

```
INSERT INTO Azioni_report (Chiusa, Data, Descrizione, ID_report, IntEst, Tipo, Responsabile) 
VALUES (0, CONVERT(date, '2-12-2014', 105), 'verifica dell''efficacia', 1049, 1, 2, 12)
```

If I run it from my "test page", it works fine. When I run the exact same query in the page where I need it, it gives this error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'efficacia'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'efficacia'. ) ) 1
```

I'm using SQL server.

Comment: This `'verifica dell''efficacia'` you have 2x `'` one beside the other. What do you want to do, add the apostrophe/quote?

Comment: Yes, I need the apostrophe there.

Comment: Try `'verifica dell'\'efficacia'` or `'verifica dell\'efficacia'`

Comment: I tried that in my test page, and just as I thought it inserts "verifica dell\'efficacia" into the database.

Comment: I made an edit to my comment above, adding another. Reload it. Being `'verifica dell\'efficacia'`

Comment: Instead of using a sql injection vulnerable approach in your code you should parameterize your query. This will protect your system and fix this problem for you.

Comment: Use sql-parameters. @Fred-ii-: you [escape an apostrophe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server) by doubling them.

Comment: Just as Sean says. Or you can use `stripslashes($var)` then `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$var)`.

Comment: Both of them give errors. First one "Incorrect syntax near '\'." Second one "Incorrect syntax near 'efficacia'." and "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ', 1049, 1, 2, 12)'."

Comment: @Sean Lange Ok, but still that doesn't explain why it runs fine in one page and gives error in another.

Comment: Probably because of the type of quotes which are encapsulating the query...

Comment: Now this is strange. I just noticed that, even if it kicks an error, the query works. I mean, the data gets into the database exactly as it is intended. How is it possible?

Comment: I couldn't say. I don't know enough about that API. I'm mostly an MySQL coder.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem where you are not escaping your quotes properly. Escaping is done by prepending them with a backslash `\` like so:

```
INSERT INTO Azioni_report 
    (Chiusa, Data, Descrizione, ID_report, IntEst, Tipo, Responsabile) 
VALUES
    (0, CONVERT(date, '2-12-2014', 105), 'verifica dell\'\'efficacia', 1049, 1, 2, 12);
```

To avoid this altogether, try reading up on PDO or mysqli and the parameterizing (or binding) of your queries in PHP:

> [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
>
> [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) - [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: As I stated, I use SQL server, and escaping quotes is done by doubling them.