# Adding ' character in sql server and PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

basically i got a text editor that will send possibly HTML tags to my table.

I'm using this text editor in my website
http://www.tinymce.com/

But what if someone uses the ' character?

I have been searching for a way to allow users to enter VARCHAR type characters in my website. In mysql there is the escape string function. What is its alternative in sqlserver. I have been searching a lot...  havent found what I am searching for so far.

Please help me out. 
Thanks ^_^

Comment: Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). Prepared statements will handle all of your special characters in data fields correctly.

Comment: You will want to use [Parameterized Queries](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/) to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: If you are just using the mssql extension (instead of PDO), you can still [bind values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php) to your queries.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use double apostrophe to get the single apostrophe inserted in your column.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO exampleTbl VALUES('I don''t know')
```

If you are using PHP you can use parameterised queries with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

As Mr. Jonathan Kuhn  has pointed in the comments, you can also look at [mssql_init](http://php.net/mssql_init) and [mssql_bind](http://php.net/mssql_bind) in case you are not using PDO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard that depends on the DBMS. In MSSQL, you double up the single quote ([SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)). This is the same as in Oracle.

Comment: True @JonathanKuhn, but escaping data is *so* 2006 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes. But the answer isn't wrong. That is how you escape quotes in MSSQL. And @Singleton, you could also point to the [mssql_init](http://php.net/mssql_init) and [mssql_bind](http://www.php.net/mssql_bind) in case OP is just using the MSSQL extension and not PDO.

Comment: I have removed those comments.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I will say that double single quotes really threw me for a loop when I first saw it also. I still don't understand why. But that