# Right way to add an apostrophe to a select query

Tags: count, spreadsheet, apostrophe

What is the right way to add an apostrophe to my select query in Google Spreadsheets?

I wan't to count how much entries there are with this string:

```
Today's
```

Current output:

```
#VALUE!
```

My query:

```
select Count(F) where F = 'Today's' Label Count(F) ''

="select Count(F) where F = '"&A3&"' Label Count(F) ''"
```

Comment: Doesn't [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server) help you?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not sure how to use this with this query? Where do I have to place the extra quotes?
     ="select Count(F) where F = '"&A3&"' Label Count(F) ''"

Comment: It's working now! Query is:
="select Count(F) where F = """&A3&""" Label Count(F) ''"

Answer (score 0):

It is already explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server).
But you just have to use double quotes to escape in most cases like

```sql
Select 'Mike''s car'
```

Here is a simple example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test (
  Name VARCHAR(25), 
  LastName VARCHAR(25), 
  Department VARCHAR(50)
);
insert into Test (Name, LastName, Department)
values 
  ('John', 'Doe', 'Something''s Department'),
  ('Jane', 'Doe', 'Another One''s Department');

select * 
from Test
where Department = 'Another One''s Department'
```

Working example in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f73fa/2)