# SQL server form entering a string with an apostrophe

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms

I have a C# form application which is linked to an SQL server database. The application relays queries to the SQL server and inputs/outputs data accordingly.

An error which came up is when I am trying to input a string which has an apostrophe in it like for example inputting `"The dog's bone"`.

Is there any way to input this since I cannot ask the user to always enter a double apostrophe as many people suggest.

This is my query which I am inputting:

```
Query = "INSERT INTO " + databaseNotes + " VALUES ('" + Release_Desc_txtBox.Text + "')";
constring = "Password=" + pass + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" + user + ";Initial Catalog=" + catalog + ";Data Source=" + datasource;
// CONNECTION TO SQL SERVER DATABASE
SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
SqlDataReader myReader;
```

Comment: By the way, why you tagged with `mysql`? It seems irrelevant to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna escape single quotes, [you need to double them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server) in your sql query as

```
The dog''s bone
```

But I don't recommend it.<sub>Which also you can't</sub>

Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead which will automatically handled these single quotes without doubling them. And this kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` automatically. As far as I see, you don't need `SqlDataReader` since you just try to use `INSERT` query.

```
using(var conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring))
using(var cmdDataBase = conDataBase.CreateCommand())
{
    // Set your CommandText property with parameters.
    // Add your parameters and their values with `Add()` method.
    // Open your connection.
    // Execute your query.
}
```

By the way, since you take your table name as an input, please do strong validation before you put it in your sql query or go for a whitelist. I hope there are only be a fixed set of *possible* correct values for your table name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Prepared statements`. These are safer to use & also prevents SQL injection attack

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Or you have to escape the user input.

But better solution is to use `Prepared Statements`