# SQL Server 2014: reading single quote comma delimiter error (',')

Tags: sql-server, ssms, delimiter

There is an example csv file:

```
category,fruits,cost 
'Fruits','Apple,banana,lemon','10.58'
```

When I import this csv into SQL Server 2014

by clicking the database in "Object explorer"=>Task=>Import data.

No matter how I play around with column delimiter options, the row 2 will always become

5 columns (Fruits,Apple,banana,lemon,10.58) instead of the desired 3 columns 
('Fruits','Apple,banana,lemon','10.58'). (So I want 'Apple,banana,lemon' to be in one column.)

The solution here  [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server) doesn't work.  Any guru could enlighten? Python, Linux bash, SQL or simple editor tricks are welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to change the delimiter to `','`? You still have to remove the very first and last one manually, but that could be easy with a SQL `UPDATE`. Not sure the delimiter option is doable in the import wizard, but might be an easy way to go at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No matter how I play around with column delimiter options

That's not the option you need to play with - it's the Text Qualifier:

[image]

And it now imports easily.