# wordpress query with quote/apostrophe varrients

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, html-entities

This is a bit of a two fold question. I've an ajax request that polles for duplicate post titles, but it's getting thrown by different quote/apostrophes and their variants, returning negative when I know there is a duplicate.

I have a post titled: "Ben’s Big Fish" ie with the apostrophe `(&rsquo;)`

But doing a query for the following always comes back negative:

```
Ben's Big Fish (&apos;)
Ben’s Big Fish (&rsquo;)
Bens Big Fish (no apos)
```

However a query for `Big Fish` returns all the variant posts titles with these words in it, including post titles with quotes and apostrophes in them.

Here are the main characters that are also causing issue:

```
Apostrophe          '   &apos;
Open single quote   ‘   &lsquo; 
Close single quote  ’   &rsquo;
--- 
Quotation mark      "   &quot;
Open double quotes  “   &ldquo; 
Close double quotes ”   &rdquo;
```

As users are often pulling text from MS Word docs etc, these characters are coming up a lot.

On the js end I encode the post title by passing it through this function before sending it via json to my ajax handler:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/‘/g, '&lsquo;').replace(/’/g, '&rsquo;').replace(/“/g, '&ldquo;').replace(/”/g, '&rdquo;');
}
```

In my php ajax hook I'm treating the incoming POST query as follows:

```
global $wpdb;
// Grab details from inbound POST array & prepare for sql
$title = html_entity_decode($_POST['post_title']); //first un-encode
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

$sim_query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' AND ID != '%d'";
$sim_results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $sim_query, $wpdb->esc_like($title), $post_id ) );
if ($sim_results)
{ // Send the results back as json }
```

So my question is 
a) how to get the query to return the obvious duplicates as expected 
b) and possibly related, there a way we can efficiently search through strings that look for all variants the appearance of apostrophe and quotation characters without multiple queries?

Comment: I'm not an regex expert in any way, but shouldn't you put \ when searching for the special characters? For instance: `.replace(/&/g, '&amp;') ` ->  `.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;')` etc?

Comment: @dingo_d thanks for pointing that out, though I don't believe escaping is necessary in this case. Webkit at least seems to handle this well either way, though older js engines might take exception. This example is derived from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/. Regardless, it hasn't affected the results of the sql query either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of the problem actually fell back to the original encoding from JS. One of the key characters that was tripping us up: `&apos;`, is not actually decoded by `html_entity_decode`, even with the `ENT_QUOTES` flag set. Instead it expects `&#039;`.

So in the end our js looks like:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#039;').replace(/‘/g, '&lsquo;').replace(/’/g, '&rsquo;').replace(/“/g, '&ldquo;').replace(/”/g, '&rdquo;');
}
```

and we decode in PHP:

```
 $title = html_entity_decode($_POST['post_title'], ENT_QUOTES,  'UTF-8' ); //first un-encode
```

Its also important to note that SQL, will balk at single quotes, and apostrophes. It requires that they be [escaped by doubling them like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586588/362445): `''`. Wordpress takes care of the escaping for us  when we use its SQL escaping class [`$wpdb->prepare`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)