# r: escape single quote in a string

Tags: sql, r, string

I have a string like `a <- "abc'def"` and I need to paste this into a longer sql string:

```
 s <- paste0("select * from x where xx ='", a, "'")
```

But the `single quote` in the middle makes it fail, I cannot manually replace `' with \'` but need to use a function.

Comment: In SQL, single quotes are escaped by doubling them:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `'` in `a` with something appropriate to your *database*, not to R. That will probably be by doubling it up: `''`.

Comment: Well the DB stores it as "abc'def"

Comment: Well, yes. Do you know what escaping means?

Answer (score 3):

In many SQL implementations, doubling achieves the escaping you want:

```
a <- "abc'def"
a <- gsub("'", "''", a)
s <- paste0("select * from x where xx ='", a, "'")

[1] "select * from x where xx ='abc''def'"
```