# Single Quote Handling in Dynamic SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using a query like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[procedure]
@Search nvarchar(100) = ''
declare @LargeComplexQuery nvarchar(max) =
'select * from People where Name like ''%' + @Search + '% order by Name'
exec sys.sp_executesql @LargeComplexQuery
```

`@Search` is populated by a program.
If the program returns a string containing a single quote the stored procedure errors, how can I handle this?

If possible, I'd like this to be handled by the stored procedure, rather than the program passing in the string.

Comment: Try replacing single quote with two single quotes inside the "@Search" string

Comment: Single quotes are escaped by doubling them up, just as you've shown us in your example.   `DECLARE @my_table TABLE (
    [value] VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO @my_table VALUES ('hi, my name''s tim.')

SELECT * FROM @my_table`  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server) credits

Comment: If `Search = ''`, you want to return all data, right?

Comment: Or do it properly without string concatenation - `sp_executesql` can take parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape the quotes after recovering the value.
And also `COALESCE` the parameter in case a `NULL` is passed to avoid the following error

```
EXEC sp_executesql NULL
```

Which would give

> Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type
>   'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Which gives the following statements

```
DECLARE @Search nvarchar(100) = '';
SET @Search = REPLACE(COALESCE(@Search, ''), '''', '''''');
SET @LargeComplexQuery = 'SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name LIKE ''%' + @Search + '%'''
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @LargeComplexQuery
```

Answer (score 4):

Either escape the quote in the application before passing the parameter, or do it in the proc:

```
declare @Search nvarchar(100) = ''
declare @Search2 nvarchar(100)
declare @LargeComplexQuery nvarchar(max)

set @Search2 = replace(@Search, '''', '''''')

set @LargeComplexQuery = 'select * from People where Name like ''%' + @Search2 + '%''' -- I escaped the quote here too
exec sys.sp_executesql @LargeComplexQuery
```

Answer (score 2):

Here as a version that uses `sp_executesql` parameters and so is not vulnerable to SQL injection - it should also provide better performance, to quote MSDN:

> Because the Transact-SQL statement itself remains constant and only
>   the parameter values change, the SQL Server query optimizer is likely
>   to reuse the execution plan it generates for the first execution.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Yourproc]
(
  @Search NVARCHAR(100) = N''
)
AS
    DECLARE @LargeComplexQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * from People WHERE Name LIKE ''%'' + COALESCE(@Search, '''') + ''%'' ORDER BY Name'
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @LargeComplexQuery, N'@Search NVARCHAR(100)', @Search = @Search
```

I've made some assumptions, such as if you pass empty string or NULL as a search condition then you get all people returned.

Testing it out - dummy schema & data:

```
CREATE TABLE People(Name NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO People(Name)
VALUES ('Mr Smith'), ('Mrs Jones'), ('Miss O'' Jones')
```

Testing stored proc execution:

```
DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(100) = N'Jones';
EXEC YourProc @Search; --Should get back both Mrs Jones and Miss O'Jones
SET @search  = N'O'' Jones';
EXEC YourProc @Search; --Should get back just Miss O'Jones 
SET @search  = N'';
EXEC YourProc @Search; --Should get everyone, same as if you passed no search value at all
SET @search = NULL
EXEC YourProc @Search; --Should get everyone
```

[MSDN Documentation on sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)