# Processing apostrophe in an update

Tags: sql

I have a situation where I have to manually normalize some data. The problem is the data has an actual single quote in it. I was hoping I have some options other than data entry...

One of my fields has data that I want to update.
it has this date > Women's Health ServicesOBGYN3

I want to update it to 'OBGYN' using the update feature.
If using double quotes:

```
update [Programmer].[dbo].[RevenueDetail$] set Dept = 'OBGYN' where Dept = "Women's Health ServicesOBGYN3"
```

I get this error.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Women's Health ServicesOBGYN3'.

If using single quotes:

```
update [Programmer].[dbo].[RevenueDetail$] set Dept = 'OBGYN' where Dept = 'Women's Health ServicesOBGYN3'
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two single quotes for each single quote in the string. e.g.

```
select 'Women''s Health ServicesOBGYN3'
```

So your update would look like:

```
update [Programmer].[dbo].[RevenueDetail$] set Dept = 'OBGYN' where Dept = 'Women''s Health ServicesOBGYN3'
```