# Loading csv file into a SQL Server database results in error

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, upload

I have this code which is trying to load a `.csv` file into a SQL Server database and dynamically create the table. I see it says there is a syntax error and an unclosed quotation mark, but I don't see it. Any ideas?

```
class DTUpload
{
    public static void CSVUploadCode()
    {
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        string LogFolder = @"C:\Log";

        try
        {
            // Declare Variables and provide values
            string SourceFolderPath = @"C:\Old\";
            string FileExtension = "*.csv";
            string FileDelimiter = ",";
            string ColumnsDataType = "NVARCHAR(max)";
            string SchemaName = "dbo";

            // Get files from folder
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolderPath, "*" + FileExtension);

            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                // Create Connection to SQL Server in which you would like to create tables and load data
                SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection();
                SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = *******; Initial Catalog = *******; User id=*******;" + "Password=*********;";

                // Writing Data of File Into Table
                string TableName = "";
                int counter = 0;
                string line;
                string ColumnList = "";

                System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);

                SQLConnection.Open();

                while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        // Read the header and prepare create table statement
                        ColumnList = "[" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "],[") + "]";
                        TableName = (((fileName.Replace(SourceFolderPath, "")).Replace(FileExtension, "")).Replace("\\", ""));
                        string CreateTableStatement = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[" + SchemaName + "].";
                        CreateTableStatement += "[" + TableName + "]')";
                        CreateTableStatement += " AND type in (N'U'))DROP TABLE [" + SchemaName + "].";
                        CreateTableStatement += "[" + TableName + "]  Create Table " + SchemaName + ".[" + TableName + "]";
                        CreateTableStatement += "([" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "] " + ColumnsDataType + ",[") + "] " + ColumnsDataType + ")";
                        SqlCommand CreateTableCmd = new SqlCommand(CreateTableStatement, SQLConnection);
                        CreateTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Prepare Insert Statement and execute to insert data
                        string query = "Insert into " + SchemaName + ".[" + TableName + "] (" + ColumnList + ") ";
                        query += "VALUES('" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','") + "')";

                        SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand(query, SQLConnection);
                        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    counter++;
                }

                SourceFile.Close();
                SQLConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Create Log File for Errors
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(LogFolder
               + "\\" + "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
            {
              sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error message I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'Annual'.
>
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '] NVARCHAR(max))'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning (TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery (TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> at ParseColumnCount.DTUpload.CSVUploadCode() in C:\ParseColumnCount\DTUpload.cs:line 66
>
> ClientConnectionId:********************
>   Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15
>
> ClientConnectionId before routing:**************
>   Routing Destination:*****************

Made the suggested changes and now am getting

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'U'.
>
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')DROP TABLE [dbo].
>   [Compensation.csv]  Create Table dbo.[Compensation.csv](["Associate
>   ID"]  NVARCHAR(max),["Position ID"] NVARCHAR(max),["Home Department
>   Code  [Employment Profile]"] NVARCHAR(max),["Annual Salary"]
>   NVARCHAR(max), ["Regular Pay Rate Amount"] NVARCHAR(max),["Standard
>   Hours"] NVARCHAR(max), ["Pay Grade Code"] NVARCHAR(max),["Pay
>   Frequency"] NVARCHAR(max), ["Compensation Change Reason Code"]
>   NVARCHAR(max),["Compensation Change  Reason Description"]
>   NVARCHAR(max))'.

Comment: `CreateTableStatement += "[" + TableName + "]')";`, remove the single quote at the end.

Comment: You should try giving us the SQL which you are trying to execute. We don't know your CSV file

Comment: You can also try to Console.WriteLine(CreateTableStatement) to see what the formatted sql statement looks like.  Or System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine if this isn't part of a Console Application.

Comment: You may also find that string.Format makes some of the string concatenation easier to read.  From C# 6 you could also use string literals.

Comment: Made the change suggested by Gusman, am getting a new similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
query += "VALUES('" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','") + "')";
```

Imagine different values for `line`.

If it contains something like

```
John Smith,Dick Brain,Harry Chest
```

Then you'll be fine.

But what if it contains

```
John Smith,Dick Brain,Harry O'Brian
```

See the problem?  In this case, `query` will get populated with

```
VALUES('John Smith,Dick brain,Harry O'Brian')
```

As far as SQL is concerned, the quote ended with Harry O, because O is followed by a single quote.  When it comes across the quote after `Brian` it finds an opening quote with no closing quote, hence the error.

You need to scrub the input for single quotes and escape them.  In SQL server, you escape them by [replacing them with double single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server), like this:

```
line = line.Replace("'","''");
query += "VALUES('" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','") + "')";
```

Then `query` will get

```
VALUES('John Smith,Dick brain,Harry O''Brian')
```

which is valid SQL.

The other (better) option would be to use a stored procedure to insert the value, and bind the string to a parameter, rather than constructing a SQL statement on the fly. If you do it that way you won't have to escape anything.

Comment: Still showing similar errors after the fixes suggested.