# Inserting a text file in to the data base c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, file, sql-insert

I am maintaining a column in **SQL server database** for storing a text file(**JSON**) with some other fields.

Type: **varchar(max)**,The column can be **null** sometimes.

A C# application reads some log files which are in JSON format and insert the file into database using insert query. The file is inserted as a string.

My problem is the JSON can file can contain single quote letters in between texts, I have faced this issue and fixed by escaping the single quote by referring this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1586560/5395773).

My questions are

1. What all are the validation or escape characters I need to be aware while sending a file as the string to the database in my c# application.
2. is there any better way to maintain a file in the database other than as varchar text.

If any points are not clear for you, please post your concerns in the comments.

I hope code snippets are not needed for this query.

Thanks.

Comment: base64 encode it or store it as a blob.

Comment: The contents of the file shouldn't matter one bit when you're trying to insert it. The basic problem here is that you're using **string concatenation** to build the SQL. **DON'T! DO! THIS!** Use parameters, at which point the contents, quotes or not, won't matter and you're not open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: If you use *prepared statements* you don't have all those problems. The framework just handles it.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen : Thanks for sharing the original post, I am somehow unable to find this in my search.