# PHP How to replace customers text area apostrophes with a escape character

Tags: php, mysql

I tried asking this question a week ago but got no answer. Hoping to explain it better this time.

My customer can input anything into a textarea and I am saving that to a MySQL table.

how can I replace all of their apostrophes with a double apostrophe so I don't get a bad query?

I tried the following it didn't work.

```
$description = str_replace("''", "'", $description);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Comment: (You may have got it backwards.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Landon have you tried this  'mysqli_real_escape_string' function ?

string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

exaple like below:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$lastname  = "O'Reilly";
$_lastname =mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $lastname);
```

https://www.php.net/mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: looks like you are using latest version of php try this mysqli_real_escape_string() function instead @LandonCall

Comment: Yup I just changed it to mysqli_real_escape_string() and just read that I needed to include my connection so the command was mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $description);

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with function.

```
str_replace(find, replace, string, count);
```

and for MySQL you should change all `'` to `''` so change your code as follow :

```
$description = str_replace("'", "''", $description);
```

Comment: Your right I think I was doing the str_replace backwards, however, I am more interested in the mysqli_real_escape_string().

Comment: In any case, you have the right answer :) @LandonCall