# How do I use single quotes as part of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a where clause that uses a string,

```
Where 
    pm.Alias = 'Toys'R'Us France'
```

However part of the string uses single quotation marks, `'R'`

How do i wrap up the whole string to pass through into my Where clause

I cannot use:

```
Where 
    pm.Alias = 'Toys''R''Us France'
```

As i need the whole string encased, as i will use this in Excel to pass this as a paramter into my query

Comment: Double them. I.e. `'Toys''R''Us France'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Comment: Specify 2 consecutive single quotes within the string literal instead of 1. `pm.Alias = 'Toys''R''Us France'`

Comment: i need to wrap the whole string from the outside in, as i use a drop down menu in Excel to pass this into my query, not all the possible entries use the single quotes

Comment: Use special characters instead of single quotes and replace it in excel parameter.

Answer (score 15):

in SQL, if you want to have Single Quotes inside a string, then you should specify it as 2 consecutive single quotes for every single quote in your string. So

```
Where 
    pm.Alias = 'Toys'R'Us France'
```

should be written as

```
Where 
    pm.Alias = 'Toys''R''Us France'
```

Comment: i need to wrap the whole string from the outside in, as i use a drop down menu in Excel to pass this into my query, not all the possible entries use the single quotes

Comment: then before passing it to the SQL query, replace each single quote with 2 singles quotes from your application code.

Comment: Your query should deal with this once passed in from Excel, or your Excel could deal with it before passing to the query: it should replace a single quote with two single quotes.

Comment: for example my other option could be 'UPIM Italy'

Comment: if you want the single quotes to be handled by the SQL, then, assign the value to a variable and in the where condition, check against the variable - then you don't have to replace the quotes. else you have to handle it in the excel or application code

Comment: how would i do that, i tried  Declare (at)store varchar(15); Set (at)store = 'Toys'R'Us France'   note cannot use propper at sign in comment

Comment: it's better go for handling it from the application code since it more easy and safe.

Answer (score 2):

You might try using extra quotes after and before the existing quotes.
In this case add quote before and after 'R', and the query will be like below.

```
Where 
    pm.Alias = 'Toys''R''Us France'
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently face this issue in my sqlite database, you can resolve using like this.

```
Where 
pm.Alias = "Toys'R'Us France"
```

use double quote (") instead of single quote (') after equal sign.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for SQLite at least.

Comment: Doesn't work for PostgreSQL either.