# How to insert json string in DB

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to insert json value in table but my json contains `'` as well hence my query is not well formatted and I get error:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string

My SQL query text in c# is as follows:

```
string query = " INSERT INTO [DGS].[DPN].CONSOLESESSIONTRACKING ([UCID], [SessionID], [MUCustomization]) VALUES(" + "'" + ucid + "'," + "'" + consoleSessionTracking.SessionId + "'" + consoleSessionTracking.cust + "'" + ") ";
```

How can I store json value containing `'` in sql? Is there any workaround?

Comment: please, USE PARAMETERS

Comment: Huma, please see the duplicate for how to fix your problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server

Comment: @Andreas That isn't really the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen this is a very, very, very bad idea. Google for `Bobby Tables`. Besides, quote what? Double quotes, single quotes or single quotes inside double quotes? All combinations are valid in JSON

Comment: @john, and panagiotis-kanavos: Indeed, I misinterpreted the question :-).

Comment: You can use SqlCommand and SqlParameter for preventing errors that you have experienced as well as preventing SQL injection problems. Please refer to http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/prevent-sql-injection-using-parameterized-query.aspx for a sample case showing how you can build a SQL command using SqlParameter and SqlCommand objects