# Erro: select * from table where column like '%tom's'

Tags: sql

I am getting `"incorrect syntax near 's'` for the below query

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: Provide us a table example and, you want to grab all "TenHang" starting with 't' having a ' inside their name?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable string contains a single quote which makes your generated SQL end before-hand. You need to escape the single quote to build correctly the SQL.

```
String sql = "select * from Hang1 where TenHang like '%" + t.replace("'", "''") + "%' ";
```

You are wide open to SQL injection, please take measures to prevent it!