# how to use ' symbol in where condition without LIKE function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with 3 columns Month, Name, Sales.
In the Month column is data like "Jun'18, Jul'18 ..."

So how can I use "Jun'18" in where condition without using `LIKE` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just have to escape the single quote like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Month = 'Jun''18'
```