# ISSUE USING "WHERE" IN PHP SQL QUERY

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

Im running the latest version of XAMPP and its connecting to a MSSQL DATABASE with the most current drivers for PHP 7.3.8 the queries are being issued using sqlsrv_query() + sqlsrv_fetch_array()

Ok so I have a SQL Query I need to run from PHP which is:

```
$sql = 'SELECT distinct "Name" FROM vItem WHERE "Name" LIKE pkg%';
```

The above code doesn't work and does not return anything but when I just run(below):

```
$sql = 'SELECT distinct "Name" FROM vItem';
```

It returns the values from the column it literally breaks after adding "WHERE" to it.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT distinct \"Name\" FROM vItem WHERE \"Name\" LIKE 'pkg%'";

Comment: I've nominated this for re-opening because the "duplicate" question is about MySQL, whereas this is about SQL Server. The syntax is different.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the backticks as changing the backticks and quotes still gives the same result!

Comment: Adding WHERE to the statement literally breaks it! ```$sql = 'SELECT distinct "Name" FROM vItem';``` works perfectly fine!

Comment: why @JayBlanchard? @demo7up tell that `$sql = 'SELECT distinct "Name" FROM vItem';` works

Comment: again ```$sql = 'SELECT distinct "Name" FROM vItem';``` works with no problem its when I extend the query with "WHERE" ```$sql = 'SELECT distinct "Name" FROM vItem WHERE "Name" LIKE pkg%';``` that it stops working

Comment: You guys are quick to assume its the backticks when its not doesnt matter which quotes, or ticks i use the result is the same!

Comment: @AndreaManzi - ```$sql = "SELECT distinct \"Name\" FROM vItem WHERE \"Name\" LIKE 'pkg%'";``` WORKED LIKE A CHARM THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: The actual answer was escaping the quotes, not which backticks or quotes were used!

Comment: The actual answer was quoting the variable `pkg&`, not escaping the quotes.

Comment: @alroc it should be duped with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server then.

Comment: OK, but what mean "Double quotes in a SQL query like you're showing is just wrong"?

Comment: I have deleted that comment @AndreaManzi

Comment: @JayBlanchard the double quotes were escaped not the single quotes

Comment: Field names are quoted by backticks, not quotes.

Comment: You have no single quotes around your variable value in your question. The vairable value must be quoted, unless it is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT distinct \"Name\" FROM vItem WHERE \"Name\" LIKE 'pkg%'";
```

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi see comments

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  $sql = "SELECT distinct \"Name\" FROM vItem WHERE \"Name\" LIKE 'pkg%'";
```