# Using 'LIKE' in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, case, sql-like

I am attempting to generate a new field based on an existing field where some of the entries contain different special characters. (ie. *, ') The special characters are at the end of the string, which is either second or third position.

I am NEW to SQL but not new to data. I am using a CASE WHEN statement. I have tried several approaches and several other commands within the CASE statement.

what I want is:

```
SELECT *
    CASE WHEN grde_code_mid LIKE '[*]' THEN 'Remedial'
         WHEN grde_code_mid LIKE '[']' THEN 'Continuing'
         ELSE NULL
    END AS class_type
FROM grde_tble
```

I keep getting the same error: "FROM keyword not found where expected". I expect to have all 3 returns in the new field.

Comment: BTW, that's a case _expression_ (since it returns a value.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for ' character you should escape it.

Change

```
WHEN grde_code_mid LIKE '[']' THEN 'Continuing'
```

by

```
WHEN grde_code_mid LIKE '['']' THEN 'Continuing'
```

Have a look at this question: [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1586560/3270427)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your query:

- you are missing a comma in the `SELECT` clause between `*` and the `CASE` expression (this is causing the error that you are currently getting)
- the bracket notations is only supported in SQL-Server; if you want to match on strings that end with `*` in a portable manner, you need expression `... LIKE '%*'`, not  `LIKE '[*]'`
- single quotes embedded in a string need to be escaped
- `SELECT *, other_field FROM ...` is not supported on all RDBMS (and, as commented by [jarhl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh), actually isn't standard ANSI SQL notation); you usually need to prefix the `*` with the table name or alias

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    g.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN grde_code_mid LIKE '%*' THEN 'Remedial'
        WHEN grde_code_mid LIKE '%''' THEN 'Continuing'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS class_type
FROM grde_tble g
```

Comment: Just a note, `SELECT *, other_column FROM ...` isnt valid ANSI SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I am still getting the hang of the language and proper terms. I am using Oracle DB. Also, yes, I did need to reference the table in the select statement (SELECT *tablename*.*). Found a work around:

CASE WHEN regexp_like(grde_code_mid, '[*]') THEN 'Remedial'
     WHEN regexp_like(grde_code_mid, '['']') THEN 'Continuing'
     ELSE NULL END AS special_class