# Error with Dynamic SQL, maybe due to apostrophe (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Please help me to find the mistakes. I think it is due to apostrophe but I dont know how to correct.

My code returned error :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>       Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'or'.

```
Use YEAR_TO_DATE;

Declare @policy NVARCHAR(MAX);
Declare @account_list NVARCHAR(MAX);
Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
Set @policy ='TTY%';
Set @account_list='18000,19000';

Set @sql = 
'Select
case
when [Debit_Account] in ('+@account_list+') and ([policy1] like '+@policy+' or [policy2] like '+@policy+' or [policy3] like '+@policy+') then -[Amount]
when [Credit_Account] in ('+@account_list+') and ([policy1] like '+@policy+' or [policy2] like '+@policy+' or [policy2] like '+@policy+') then [Amount]
else 0
end as [Amount]
from CTGS 
where [Debit_Account] in ('+@account_list+') or [Credit_Account] in ('+@account_list+')';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Comment: [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) allows you to use parameters. You should rework the script to use them.

Comment: That code is product specific? Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add string delimiter quotes into your dynamic SQL string.

Your code (*repeated several times*):

```
' .... [policy1] like '+@policy+' .... '
```

If you add this:

```
DECLARE @qt VARCHAR(1) = CHAR(39)
```

Then you can fix the problem by using this (*also several times*):

```
' .... [policy1] like '+@qt+@policy+@qt+' .... '
```

Note that instead of `@qt` you can also use `''` (two single quotes) directly in your strings where it is needed, but in my opinion that often produces hard-to-read code.

Also note that if `@policy` could itself also contain one or more quotes, you'd have to escape those with a `REPLACE` as follows:

```
' .... [policy1] like '+@qt + REPLACE(@policy, @qt, @qt+@qt) + @qt+' .... '
```

Comment: It would be easier and safer to use `@policy` as a proper parameter  *inside* the query string ie `policy1 like @policy or policy2 like @policy ...` and pass the value as a parameter value to `sp_executesql`.