# Escaping single quotes in string

Tags: sql, sapb1

Wasnt really sure how to phrase this title, every time I think I have this figured out it always comes back to trip me up.

I am using B1 Boyum and storing a string in a variable.

The code looks like this

```
@STORE30 = '(T3.ItmsGrpNam LIKE 'Comm%%' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = 'Vended Ancillary' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = 'Merchant Fee and CC' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = 'Laundry P&A')'
```

However this gives me unexpected END errors, ive tried escaping with + on either side of the first one ('Comm%%') which doesnt give me the unexpected end error but stops the string at T3.ItmsGrpNam LIKE

I need to have the whole string including the apostrophes of each of in between.

One day I will get the hang of this, happy to read some resources on best practices if someone can also supply some links.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi @nyedidikek, tried the doubling up of quotes, didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
@Store30 = '(T3.ItmsGrpNam LIKE ''Comm%%'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Vended Ancillary'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Merchant Fee and CC'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Laundry P&A'')'
```

When you want to escape the single quotes just use a double single quotes there.

Comment: Yeah I tried doubling up on apostrophes. end result is just ```T3.ItmsGrpNam LIKE``` , it doesnt even get to 'Comm%%' ...

Comment: Are you sure? I'm trying this in my MSSQL 

`DECLARE @STORE30 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(T3.ItmsGrpNam LIKE ''Comm%%'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Vended Ancillary'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Merchant Fee and CC'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Laundry P&A'')'
PRINT @Store30`


And i get this

**(T3.ItmsGrpNam LIKE 'Comm%%' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = 'Vended Ancillary' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = 'Merchant Fee and CC' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = 'Laundry P&A')**

Comment: could it have something to do with it being a macro in B1 Usability Package? I swear ive come across this before and there was a solution but for the life of me i cant remember..

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
@STORE30 = SQL(SELECT 'T3.ItmsGrpNam LIKE ''Comm%%'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Vended Ancillary'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Merchant Fee and CC'' OR T3.ItmsGrpNam = ''Laundry P&A''')
```