# How to save a string that contains both single and double quotes to postgres column

Tags: postgresql

I have the following string:

SELECT hello as "helloHello", '' as "empty" FROM tbl_test

I want to do something like this:

INSERT INTO tbl_x (a, b, c) VALUES (x, y, string_from_above)

The strings are going to be dynamic (basically they're strings of sql statements), so I do not want to escape all the ' and ". If I open the postgres database and double click on the varchar column, I can copy and paste the string and it goes in exactly as it looks. I want to be able to programmatically do so. Is there a way using an insert command? I tried using pgFormat, but that didn't work. See attached pic with what it looks like in the table.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server

Comment: No. I just added an image of what the value looks like in the postgres table. I'm able to add it if I double click and paste, but not via an sql statement.

Comment: for that you also use escape char like `\"` and `\'` like `var str = "friend\'s \"cat\"";`

Comment: Not quite sure what you are after. Does this work: `INSERT INTO tbl_x (a, b, c) VALUES (x, y, quote_literal(string_from_above));`

Comment: Can't see the image...  can you double check?

Answer (score 0):

All PostgreSQL APIs worth their money have a way to escape strings for inclusion in a dynamic SQL statement.

For example, if you write in C, you can use libpq's [`PQescapeLiteral()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-ESCAPE-STRING).

There are also SQL functions for this: `quote_literal()` and [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT). They can be used in PL/pgSQL code.

Don't try to write your own code for this. Use prior art and avoid the risk of getting it wrong.