# Insert query in SQL with data that has single quotes

Tags: sql, node.js

Here is my insert query

```
INSERT INTO
    Customers (CustomerId, ContactNumber, MsgContent, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES 
    (1, '123456', '["https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300","Gift your Dear one' s with surprise gifts"," abc "," 123 "," xyz "]', ' mno ', 012, ' pqr ') ;
```

SQL is showing syntax error while executing this query.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Search stackoverflow first for similar questions. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? I think the ' by the text one's is causing an issue.  It closes the opening ' before [ in MsgContent.

Comment: Normally, you can fix this issue by having double quote, so it would not be "Gift your Dear one' s" but "Gift your Dear one'' s"

Comment: this is why you should use bind parameters if possible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using backticks here as it'll allow you use " and ' at the same time. For example, try the following for your VALUES:

```
INSERT
    INTO
    Customers (CustomerId,ContactNumber, MsgContent, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES 
(1,'123456',`["https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300","Gift your Dear one' s with surprise gifts," abc "," 123 "," xyz "]`, ' mno ', 012, ' pqr ') ;
```

Note the backticks that open and close your MsgContent field.

Comment: Backticks are used to quote "identifier names", like table/column/database names.