# How to pass a JSON in Query Function and escape single Quotes

Tags: javascript, quotes

So im trying to pass a JSON in a Query to save in the Database.
But i can't figure out how to escape that single quote mark at **"Don't".** I've tried **\'** but i still can't pass it.

`` pgClient.query(`INSERT INTO data VALUES(83, '{ "name": "John Doe", "items": ["Don't", "Drink"] }')`) ``

Note: I've used the **`** quote since i was passing the JSON as an object.

Comment: look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586588/18278998

Comment: Don't write strings containing strings containing strings. We'll all get headaches. Use parametrised queries instead.

Comment: In one of my projects I have `const sql = 'INSERT INTO user_data VALUES($1, $2)'; const result = await client.query(sql, [userId, data]);` where `data` is a User *object*. The conversion to JSON is all taken care of by the API. (the `data` column is defined as `data jsonb`)

Comment: @rbdeenk worked, parametrised queries is the way

Comment: completely agree, parameterized queries also decrease the chance of SQL injection.