# How to add special character in parameter to a stored procedure in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, escaping, ssms

I have to execute a stored procedure which expects a single quote (`'`) in parameter. I'm using this, but this isn't working:

```
exec sp_promo_db_list_generic_search_by_sales_order 
        '1','1', 'logo_name','Hamley's', 'N','N''
```

I am getting the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 's'.

I am expecting that the stored procedures accepts `'` character in the parameter. I've tried using the escape character(`'Hamley/'s'`) still it isn't working.

Comment: You need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server) the single quote: `exec sp_promo_db_list_generic_search_by_sales_order '1','1', 'logo_name', 'Hamley''s', 'N','N'`. And it's not clear what are the actual values of the last two parameters.

Comment: Thanks ,I tried using escaping character by doubling the quotes but it isn't working.Same goes for using SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

Comment: You need to escape only the single quotes inside the string literal (`'Hamley''s'`, not `''Hamley''s''`).

Comment: Yes, tried this only. Still not working.

Comment: Repeat the same character twice: '' instead '

Comment: @ChaitanyaGalande can you share your SQL after making the changes Bogdan suggested? Running this very simple query worked for me `SELECT 'Hamley''s'` so keen to see what you've changed

Comment: Considernig that typing in SELECT 'Hamley''s' into SSMS works just fine, is there something in the SP that's causing the error?

Comment: @Antony , the execute statement after the changes was -
 exec sp_promo_db_list_generic_search_by_sales_order 
    '1','1', 'logo_name','Hamley''s', 'N','N'

Comment: @John actually this works only for the select statemnt ,for using it in paramter in a stored procedure (which expects more than one parameter) it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

If you are using single quotes in ' ' then Always add one more single quotes.

```
    exec sp_promo_db_list_generic_search_by_sales_order 
    '1','1', 'logo_name','Hamley''s', 'N','N'
```

Comment: I tried the same ,for some reason it's  not working. I'm getting the same error
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
for 
exec sp_promo_db_list_generic_search_by_sales_order 
    '1','1', 'logo_name','Hamley''s', 'N','N'

Comment: can you post the stored proc script?

Comment: SET QUERY = 'INSERT INTO #TEMP
    SELECT *
    FROM sales_orders
    where sales_orders.trans_flag = ''A''     
    AND '  +  as_column_name + ' like '  + '''%'  + as_search_value  + '%'' '  +
    as_closed_order_condition + as_sub_order_condition + as_estimate_no_condition
    + 'ORDER BY trans_date desc,trans_no desc '

EXECUTE(QUERY);

Here , as_search_value   is Hamley's . 
I've removed the @ here because stackoverflow wasn't allowing the @ sign in comment