# How to use REPLACE with string containing apostrophe?

Tags: sql-server, string, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace single quote in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440733/replace-single-quote-in-sql-server)

So I'm trying to use the following code:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = REPLACE(FieldName, 'SearchFor', 'ReplaceWith');
```

It works wonderfully for what I need to do, except for the fact that what I need to search for is "valid driver's license". That apostrophe doesn't seem to agree with the code. I tried doing this:

```
'valid driver''s license'
```

...but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.
```

If anyone has dealt with this before, I would love some help! This would save me so much time, rather than updating each record by hand. -__-

Ellie

Comment: Someone in SQL Chat just helped me out. I needed to cast my field to a VARCHAR. It didn't like that it was a text field.

Comment: Are you passing these strings from a code (like c sharp) or running this on sql server management studio?

Comment: you can surround the expression with double quotes to escape the single quote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is. `FieldName` is a column of type `text`, which doesn't work with the `REPLACE` function. Try casting the first param as `VARCHAR(MAX)` first, and it should work. IE:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = REPLACE(CAST(FieldName AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'SearchFor', 'ReplaceWith');
```

Answer (score 1):

That's funny. I just ran into this exact thing a few minutes ago. It turns out I had to change this:

UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = REPLACE(FieldName, 'SearchFor', 'ReplaceWith');

to this:
UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = REPLACE(cast(FieldName as varchar(5000)), 'SearchFor', 'ReplaceWith');

Answer (score -1):

You must escape the single quote with a slash.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = REPLACE(FieldName, 'Isn\'t', 'Is not');
```

Comment: In MSSQL, you escape apostrophe's by doubling them up. In other words: `REPLACE(FieldName, 'Isn''t', 'Is not')`

Comment: @SPFiredrake, my bad, for some reason I thought this question was tagged MySQL