# Replace single quotes in SSIS

Tags: ssis

In SSIS I have an email address stored in a variable. The person's name in the email address has a single quote which is confusing sql server.

Something such as

```
    Select field1, field2, from mytable where cust_emlad_tx = ?
```

cust_emlad_tx   contains a name such as Jim.O'Dowell@something.com

How could I replace that with two single quotes so that sql server will process it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what "confusing SQL Server" actually means? Using variables usually avoids issues with quoting, so it's not clear what the problem really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440733/replace-single-quote-in-sql-server) that might help you with the single quotes. The general practice is to replace the single quote with 2 single quotes and that does not confuse the SQL Server when processing the strings.