# Escaping single quote in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to execute the below statement to escape single quotes (i.e. using two single quotes):

```
declare @year varchar(max)
set @year = '111,11';
exec ('SELECT * FROM SplitValues(' + @year + ','','')');
```

I even tried to use `char(39)` instead of quotes:

```
declare @year varchar(max)
set @year = '111,11';
exec ('SELECT * FROM SplitValues(' + @year + ',' + char(39) + ',' + char(39) + ')');
```

But it didn't help. These are the only two solutions that I found on this site. Any help?

This is the simplified query to clear up all your questions:

```
declare @year varchar(max)
set @year = '111,11';
SELECT * FROM SplitValues(@year , ',')
```

I want to achieve this, but using a dynamic query.

Comment: Why do you need to use EXEC at all here?

Comment: this is because the query on which i am working right now is very complex and cannot be posted here. this is just a glimpse of what i  am trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Replace single quotes in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440733/replace-single-quotes-in-sql-server)*.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A word of advice. When testing a dynamic script, first just display it instead of executing it. That way you will be able to see it exactly as it would be seen by the `EXEC` statement.

Now to the issue. You should keep in mind that you are not passing the *variable* to `SplitValues` but are instead concatenating the variable's value into the script. Since the value is `varchar`, it should be concatenated with quotation marks around it. The absence of them is the only problem really.

The quotes around the second argument, the comma, are escaped correctly *in both cases*. So, just use either of the methods to add the quotes around the first argument:

- repetition of the quotation mark:

  ```
  DECLARE @year varchar(max), @sql varchar(max);
  SET @year = '111,11';
  SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM SplitValues(''' + @year + ''','','')';
  SELECT @sql;
  ```
- using `CHAR(39)`:

  ```
  DECLARE @year varchar(max), @sql varchar(max);
  SET @year = '111,11';
  SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM SplitValues(' + CHAR(39) + @year + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + ')';
  SELECT @sql;
  ```

Obviously, the first method is more compact, but, like I said, both work well, as [this SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11135) clearly shows.

Note, however, that you could easily escape this issue in the first place, if you pardon the pun. Instead of `EXEC ()`, you could use `EXEC sp_executesql`, which allows you to use *parameters*. Here's the same script rewritten to use `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @year varchar(max), @delim char(1);
SET @year = '111,11';
SET @delim = ',';
EXEC sp_executesql
  N'SELECT * FROM SplitValues(@year_param,@delim_param)',
  N'@year_param varchar(max), @delim_param char(1)',
  @year,@delim;
```

As you can see, no need to worry about escaping the quotes: SQL Server takes the trouble of substituting the values correctly, not you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. What is the issue you are observing here?

Comment: I wanted to point to the irony in your initial statement that you should print the command instead of executing it for verification, but sp_executesql doesn't give you the option to print the statement without executing it. If there is a way, perhaps you should demonstrate it.  

I guess the printing out the statement is of limited utility since it's more readable than the alternatives.

Comment: If the dynamic query doesn't contain any name parametrisation (and there was none in this case), it doesn't need to be built out of many parts glued together. So yes, using a variable to store the query merely to print it before/instead of its execution would appear to be of little value.

Comment: use CHAR (39) I liked

Answer (score 16):

Just type single quote two times:

```
select 'that''s it'
```

Comment: This is the first thing which i tried as you can see in my posted solution.

Comment: Not exactly. ' + char(39) + ' gives you three quotes, while you need four. Let's try the entire statement:
exec ('SELECT * FROM SplitValues(''' + @year + ''','''','''')');

Answer (score 3):

Ok... you want to take this string:

```
SELECT * FROM SplitValues(@year , ',')
```

And make it a string like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM SplitValues('111,11' , '','')'
```

So, your final code would be:

```
declare @year varchar(max), @sql varchar(max)
set @year = '111,11';
set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM SplitValues(''' + @year + ''' , '''','''')'

select @sql
```

Actually, finally select you would use `exec()` instead. However you really should probably use `sp_sqlexecute` for stuff like this since you can use paramaterized queries.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @var1 varchar(100)
declare @var3 varchar(100)
declare @var4 varchar(100)

declare @var2 nvarchar(MAX)
set @var1 = ‘anil’
set @var4 = ‘1019518594’

set @var2 = N’select
a.*
from card b
join log a on a.Cust = b.ID
where a.c = ”’ + @var1 + ”’ and b.s =”’+ @var4 +””

print(@var2)

exec sp_executesql @var2
```