# How to Pass Multi Value strings as single parameter to BCP query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

here am facing problem to pass multivalues parameter to bcp query.

In my scenario parameters are

```
@CustomFieldsHeaders ='CS Check','CS Date','CS Drop','CS Radio','RSP Text','RSP Date','RSP Check','RSP radio','RSP Drp','DOB'
```

I need to pass the above as a single parameter.

Following is my query for reference, please help

```
  DECLARE @CustomFieldsHeaders AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @CustomFieldsHeaders = COALESCE(@CustomFieldsHeaders+',' ,'') + ''''+CAST(FieldName as varchar(max))+''''  FROM ManageFields
        PRINT @CustomFieldsHeaders


        DECLARE @CustFieldNames VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @CustFieldNames =''+ COALESCE(@CustFieldNames+',' ,'') + CAST(ContactFieldName as varchar(max))+''
        from ManageFields
        print  @CustFieldNames

   DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(8000) 
   DECLARE @StoredProcedure AS VARCHAR(8000) 
     SET @StoredProcedure=N'"EXEC  QA31_28thNov2013.dbo.GetAllRecsBasedOnListIds_BCPTest_1 117, NULL, '+@CustFieldNames+', '''+@CustomFieldsHeaders+''' " '         
        SET @SQL = N'bcp '+@StoredProcedure + ' queryout '+'D:\BCP_WEBREPORT\QA_v1_23rdSep2013\BounceReport\12-07-13\TESTREPORT13.CSV'  +' -c -t, -S PSPL-06 -Usa -Psa!2013'  
        PRINT @SQL 
        EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @SQL
```

Comment: What's the error you got? Could you show us the last `@SQL` print value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the 's in the string?  you can escape a ' with ''.  There's a function that will do it for you called QUOTENAME() 
There's also a [similar question with some solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408986/escaping-single-quote-in-sql-server).